# Include .so library in apk in android studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I am trying my hands on developing a simple android application in which I am trying to use [sqlcipher](http://sqlcipher.net/), which uses .so libraries internally. I have read the documentation on [how to use sqlcipher with android app](http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-for-android/). I have followed the steps and it compiles without any error. But, at runtime it throws `UnsatisfiedLinkError`.

Googling around for it, I found that, [gradle doesn't support .so libraries yet](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/SOs6mxZGjMM), but I found a hack [here](https://gist.github.com/khernyo/4226923) which I am trying to use. But it throws compile time error at line #40 on the gist which is,

```
tasks.withType(com.android.build.gradle.PackageApplicationTask) { pkgTask ->
    pkgTask.jniDir new File(buildDir, 'native-libs')
}
```

saying

> Could not find property 'com' on Project 'MyProject'

Here I am posting code from my build.gradle file.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-codec.jar')
    compile files('libs/guava-r09.jar')
    compile files('libs/sqlcipher.jar')
}

targetCompatibility = 1.6
sourceCompatibility = 1.6

android {
    target = 'android-14'

    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }    

}

task copyNativeLibs(type: Copy) {
    from(new File(project(':MyProject').buildDir, 'native-libs')) { include '**/*.so' }
    into new File(buildDir, 'native-libs')
}

tasks.withType(Compile) { compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn copyNativeLibs }

clean.dependsOn 'cleanCopyNativeLibs'

tasks.withType(com.android.build.gradle.PackageApplicationTask) { pkgTask ->
    pkgTask.jniDir new File(buildDir, 'native-libs')
}
```

Can, anybody please help me on what I have done wrong or what should I do to include those .so libraries in my apk?

As I am new to android development and gradle, please apologize me if I have misunderstood something.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I had the same problem. Check out the comment in https://gist.github.com/khernyo/4226923#comment-812526

It says:

> for gradle android plugin v0.3 use "com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication"

That should fix your problem.

Comment: Works in v0.4 as well, although I had to modify the copy command's "from" to grab the so files out of the project directory instead of the build directory.

Comment: I had to change the project(':MyProject').buildDir to project(':MyProject').getProjectDir() to make it work, using Android studio 0.3.6 and com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+

Comment: As of Android Gradle 0.7.2 you can put your native libraries in src/main/jniLibs and they'll be packaged correctly.  

Sample : https://github.com/commonsguy/sqlcipher-gradle/tree/master/src/main/jniLibs

Comment: Right answer is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667903/android-studio-gradle-and-ndk/25067178#25067178

Comment: @RiyazMohammedIbrahim has by far the simplest approach for getting your *.so's to be found, that worked great for me using AS 0.8.11! What formerly I had under `libs/armeabi-v7a/` in Eclipse was picked up under `src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/`

Comment: I tried this with Android Studio 1.0.1 and gradle version 2.2.1 but it did not work. Any clues?

Comment: Refer my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27532062/android-studio-include-pre-compiled-static-library-using-ndk/28430178#28430178

Comment: It feels like Gradle is very poorly documented even though it has tons of doc pages.

Comment: Check out @Riyaz Mohammed's comment on one of the answers below.  It's a more recent and correct/easy solution!

Answer (score 257):

I've tried the solution presented in the accepted answer and it did not work for me.
I wanted to share what DID work for me as it might help someone else. I've found this solution [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/adt-dev/nQobKd2Gl_8).

Basically what you need to do is put your `.so` files inside a a folder named `lib` (Note: it is not `libs` and this is not a mistake). It should be in the same structure it should be in the `APK` file.

In my case it was:
Project:
|--lib:
|--|--armeabi:
|--|--|--.so files.

So I've made a lib folder and inside it an armeabi folder where I've inserted all the needed .so files. I then zipped the folder into a `.zip` (the structure inside the zip file is now lib/armeabi/*.so) I renamed the `.zip` file into `armeabi.jar` and added the line `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')` into `dependencies {}` in the gradle's build file.

This solved my problem in a rather clean way.

Comment: best answer until the support in studio is there

Comment: in debug BuildType everything works perfectly, but when I added proguard in release BuildType , a library can't load the log is `No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.hotelvp.caoniu/lib/liblocSDK3.so 0x41d7e268, skipping init`.  I unzip the apk, `lib/armeabi/liblocSDK3.so`  exists. do you have a similar problem?

Comment: @AssafGamliel Cool, but how do you work around the first compilation not finding the armeabi.jar dependency? Do you just build twice?

Comment: @aelam: I didn't have a similar problem, make sure the hierarchy of files are correct.

Comment: @snowdragon: I think I used clean and then build.

Comment: Is this still the best method? Or has Android Studio added support since?

Comment: When I updated Android Studio to 0.3.2 (on Mac), the problem occurred. It's a strange problem, this resolution works perfectly.

Comment: That's work for me !!! (Android Studio 0.3.5, gradle 0.6.+)

Comment: For me the line was already there, so I just had to zip.

Comment: I can confirm that this workaround indeed works - oddly enough it does not work for other archives like tar.bz2 - it seems they are silently ignored! Lets hope the Android Gradle plugin will handle this sooner rather than later...

Comment: I have posted my answer in the below mentioned link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20900814/add-pre-built-so-files-in-project-using-gradle-0-7-3

Comment: after wasting hours on this (stupid) thing, i can state that you SIR DESERVE A BEER!

Comment: @AssafGamliel thank you so much for the answer, but I am still getting an UnsatisfiedLinkError at runtime. I believe it has something to do with my file structure because I am confused if I should be putting the lib folder at the top level of my project or in my "app" module. If you could take a look at my project structure here, it would be greatly appreciated: http://i.imgur.com/4nENTdm.png

Comment: @Richard Did you clean the project after setting it up as described?

Comment: @AssafGamliel I did, but the error still persists. I don't understand how the "compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar'" line makes sense if I do not have an folder actually named "libs". I only have the "lib" folder.

Comment: @AssafGamliel Wow, I was an idiot. I put the armeabi.jar file with the structure you told us to, and just had to put that in a folder called "libs". Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why isn't the accepted answer? @Rumit Parakhiya

Comment: Thank you :), I don't know you but I appreciate it :D. Glad I could help.

Comment: Worked for me too, using Android Studio 1.1.0

Comment: This worked for me on Android Studio 1.2.2, thank you

Comment: This stopped working for me with gradle > 1.3. Check Riyaz Mohammed Ibrahims comment above - it woirks perfectly!

Comment: This is working for me too but i am getting the error on marshmallow. i.e., "file not fount libtbb.so" Please help me.

Comment: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for java.lang.String

Comment: i have .so file of other app that i have decompile i don't have native-lib.cpp file of that .so means i don't have native code i only have .so can i integrate and run it in my project because when i m runing the project this error is coming java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for int com.krunal.camarademo.Libs.nativesystem.DMDHDR.getBracketedCount() (tried Java_com_krunal_camarademo_Libs_nativesystem_DMDHDR_getBracketedCount and Java_com_krunal_camarademo_Libs_nativesystem_DMDHDR_getBracketedCount__)

Answer (score 68):

To include native libraries you need:

1. create "jar" file with special structure containing ".so" files;
2. include that file in dependencies list.

To create jar file, use the following snippet:

```
task nativeLibsToJar(type: Zip, description: 'create a jar archive of the native libs') {
    destinationDir file("$buildDir/native-libs")
    baseName 'native-libs'
    extension 'jar'
    from fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '**/*.so')
    into 'lib/'
}

tasks.withType(Compile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn(nativeLibsToJar)
}
```

To include resulting file, paste the following line into "dependencies" section in "build.gradle" file:

```
compile fileTree(dir: "$buildDir/native-libs", include: 'native-libs.jar')
```

Comment: `Compile` task has been deprecated. Use `JavaCompile` instead.

Comment: I used this answer over Assaf's answer because it makes it an automated process. Additionally, there are many ways to manually make a zip file, and some of those methods introduce unnecessary files.

Comment: This doesn't really work for me because on a clean build (`./gradlew clean`), native-libs.jar isn't included in the first build after clean (inside the APK). Later builds (if not cleaned) work fine. This is somewhat of a problem for our build server script. Anyone has any solution for this? I'm currently using Gradle (wrapper) 1.8 and "com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.3".

Comment: As of Android Gradle 0.7.2 you can put your native libraries in src/main/jniLibs and they'll be packaged correctly.  

Sample : https://github.com/commonsguy/sqlcipher-gradle/tree/master/src/main/jniLibs

Comment: Add following to build.gradle:       sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }

Comment: @Riyaz Mohammed Ibrahim, this should be an answer. It is hard to find in the comments area.

Comment: @RiyazMohammedIbrahim has the answer.. this was is SO much more simple!

Comment: @RiyazMohammedIbrahim Maybe wanna put this as an answer? I searched long for it and still apply's on gradle 1.0.0.

Comment: @all since this answer is marked as duplicate I can't answer now, you guys can upvote my comment so it will come up so others can easily find out

Comment: Correction use `JavaCompile` instead of `Compile`. It worked for me at least: `tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn(nativeLibsToJar)
}`

Comment: i have .so file of other app that i have decompile i don't have native-lib.cpp file of that .so means i don't have native code i only have .so can i integrate and run it in my project because when i m runing the project this error is coming java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for int com.krunal.camarademo.Libs.nativesystem.DMDHDR.getBracketedCount() (tried Java_com_krunal_camarademo_Libs_nativesystem_DMDHDR_getBracketedCount and Java_com_krunal_camarademo_Libs_nativesystem_DMDHDR_getBracketedCount__)

Comment: where to put the task .. and how to run the script to convert it into jar?