# Adding a .so file in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to add an external library, Scandit. I keep getting this error:

```
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load scanditsdk-android-3.3.1 from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/com.clover.barcode2-1.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/com.clover.barcode2-1]: findLibrary returned null
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
   .....
```

I assume it is because I am not properly including the .so file that comes with the library, but I can't figure out how to do it.

I am using Android Studio and I added the library by going to module settings -> libraries and added the directory with the jar and the directory with the so file.

Comment: how do you add the `.so` and put it to what directory?

Comment: I just added the directory it is in because I don't know how to add it. They are both located in /libs

Comment: add a .so file from directory outside android project: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50713933/add-so-prebuilt-library-from-another-directory-to-apk

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can add pre built *.so files in Android Studio using gradle 0.7.2+. First create the jniLibs at this location /app/src/main/ location and copy the all the folder with *.so files (armeabi, armeabi-v7a, mips, x86) in the jniLibs.

[image]

Comment: You saved my life bro, I'm trying to 2½ hours, worked perfectly, all the strange errors are gone, thank you for sharing your wisdom. @Josh Wilson You can mark as a solution?

Comment: @TGMCians can you please show us gradle piece of code which require for compile .so files.

Comment: Thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaanks you helped a lot.

Comment: can you please guide me to add lib that is written in C in my android project.

Comment: What is Core class? Can't find it

Comment: Is there any doc for the place to put `so` files?

Comment: @TGMCians You are great.. :)

Comment: Is prebuilt .hpp file required  for cmake. Its urgent please give me reply

Comment: Highly appreciate that answer. Thank you. However, is it normal that people like me, coming from a C++ world, struggles so much at finding this answer ? There's almost no documentation that I could find on the native development for Android website. Is it poor documentation or am I just ignorant ?

Answer (score 9):

To use native-library (so files)
You need to add some codes in the "build.gradle" file.

This code is for cleaing "armeabi" directory and copying 'so' files into "armeabi" while 'clean project'.

```
task copyJniLibs(type: Copy) {
    from 'libs/armeabi'
    into 'src/main/jniLibs/armeabi'
}
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn(copyJniLibs)
}
clean.dependsOn 'cleanCopyJniLibs'
```

I've been referred from the below.
https://gist.github.com/pocmo/6461138

Comment: dont forget to add armeabi-v7 and x86!

Answer (score 6):

I had a libs folder in my project where i included external libraries added the line compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar') into dependencies {} in the gradle's build file.

Then I made a lib folder and inside it an armeabi folder where I've inserted all the needed .so files. I then zipped the folder into a .zip (the structure inside the zip file is now lib/armeabi/*.so) I renamed the .zip file into armeabi.jar 
and added it to the libs folder as an external library.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a problem of the new gradle build system. Try the solution of this [answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17131418) There is also a link to a google group discussion, that describes solution and the problems more detailed.

Answer (score -1):

```
splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'x86', 'x86_64', 'arm64-v8a', 'armeabi-v7a', 'armeabi'
        universalApk false
    }
}
```

I get this code from facebook fresco library

Comment: Isnt this code for splitting the apk into smaller parts as per dependent systems so that overall apk size gets reduced?