# Unable to load library 'iengine_ansi_iso': Native library (android-arm/libiengine_ansi_iso.so) not found in resource path (.)

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, jna

There is a very weird situation. I am using [this](https://github.com/lunter/ansi_iso_sdk_java_connector) project in my Android Application. To use it, I have to include `JNA` in my project. SO I downloaded `jar` file of JNA from [here](https://jar-download.com/?detail_search=g%3A%22net.java.dev.jna%22%20AND%20a%3A%22jna%22%20AND%20v%3A%224.5.0%22&a=jna). All is good to go. BUT when I ran the project, it gave me `UnsatisfiedLinkError` for `libjnidispatch.so` file. I downloaded my desired architecture from [this link](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/tree/master/lib/native) and re-ran the project. This error is gone and here comes the new one.

```
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'iengine_ansi_iso': Native library (android-arm/libiengine_ansi_iso.so) not found in resource path (.)
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:303)
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:427)
at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:179)
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:569)
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:544)
at com.foreepay.fingerprintextraction.ansiiso.AnsiIso$AnsiIsoNative.<clinit>(AnsiIso.java:55)
at com.foreepay.fingerprintextraction.ansiiso.AnsiIso.isoCreateTemplate(AnsiIso.java:500)
at com.foreepay.fingerprintextraction.fingerprint.core.ProcessImage.doInBackground(ProcessImage.java:163)
at com.foreepay.fingerprintextraction.fingerprint.core.ProcessImage.doInBackground(ProcessImage.java:39)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

I tried to do exactly the same in this case. Downloaded the required file from [here](https://github.com/lunter/ansi_iso_sdk_java_connector/tree/master/doc), put it in folder (`src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a`), but no luck. Since then I tried every possible way to add `*.so` file in Android Studio Project, but it failed every time.

These are the links which I have tried to add `.so` file but every one has almost the same solution, which is not working in my case OR maybe my case is not their case.

1. [Adding a .so file in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16705954/adding-a-so-file-in-android-studio)
2. [How to include *.so library in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357687/how-to-include-so-library-in-android-studio)
3. [Android NDK: how include *.so files in AndroidStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33164778/android-ndk-how-include-so-files-in-androidstudio)

And some more.

I am still unable to find the cause. Here is a code block which is causing the issue.

```
final AnsiIsoNative INSTANCE = (AnsiIsoNative) Native.loadLibrary("iengine_ansi_iso", AnsiIsoNative.class);
```

Where `Native` is a `JNA` class.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Run JNA with `-Djna.debug_load=true` to see where JNA is looking for the resource.  It checks a few different places.  Then either make sure your resource is found in that path, or provide an absolute file path to the VM.  Android is kind of a special case since the native libraries are integrated with the project in a different way than other systems.

Comment: @technomage I tried setting up `-Djna.debug_load=true` by going in Help>Edit Custom VM Options on Android Studio. Restarted Android Studio but still JNA doesn't show the full path in error.

Comment: Still stuck on the same error mentioned by @waqas-ahmed-ansari.

Comment: IIRC, you can't dynamically load shared libraries on android with a custom path; they are only available if built with the project, and then they appear on the system library load path.

Comment: Add some code to verify that `System.getProperty("jna.debug_load")` is actually being set.  I believe that it should find the library when it attempts a load without any explicit path.  For reference, see [JavaDoc for NativeLibrary](https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.5.0/javadoc/index.html?com/sun/jna/NativeLibrary.html)