# libtensorflow_demo.so not found, tracking unavailable

Tags: android, tensorflow

I'm trying the object `detection API` ([Git repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android)) from `Tensorflow` with `android` and when I build the project with `bazel` everything works fine and the `libstensorflow_demo`.so is there and loads normally. But when I try to to build the project with **Gradle** only and manually add the library to the `JniLibs` following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16705954/adding-a-so-file-in-android-studio) and this [Github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15916) but I get the error mentioned in the title with an other error :

```
ObjectTracker: Native object tracking support not found. See tensorflow/examples/android/README.md for details.
```

Anyone encountered this problem?

Comment: Did you finally solve this issue? I am having the exact same problem.

Comment: yes i did find a solution. I opened an issue in [TensorFlow's Git repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/19384#issuecomment-392705318) where i shared my solution. I hope it helps you