# call function from a shared lib in an Android application

Tags: java, android, android-studio, shared-libraries

I am struggling to use a shared library in an Android application.

I've downloaded the [jsqlite shared libs](https://github.com/geopaparazzi/libjsqlite-spatialite-android/blob/master/archive/20150616.libjsqlite.4.3.0.tar.bz2) and unzipped these into my project to the HelloSpatialite/app/src/main/jniLibs directory. SO posts ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17522164/how-to-copy-or-use-native-libs-with-android-studio-gradle-build/27103930#27103930)) say this is all you need to do in recent Android Studio versions.

This is my directory listing:

> HelloSpatialite/app/src/main/jniLibs]: ls -l */*.so
>
> -rwxr-xr-x@ 1 user  staff   7778576 Jun 16 22:40 armeabi-v7a/libjsqlite.so
>
> -rwxr-xr-x@ 1 user  staff   7782620 Jun 16 22:30 armeabi/libjsqlite.so
>
> -rwxr-xr-x@ 1 user  staff  12080476 Jun 16 22:51 x86/libjsqlite.so

I verified the shared library is included in the APK [as in step 3 here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27421134/system-loadlibrary-couldnt-find-native-library-in-my-case/27523384#27523384)

However, now I am not able to use the classes and functions from this library.

If [my java code](https://github.com/kristina-hager/hello-world-spatialite/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/kristina/hellospatialite/GeoDatabaseHandler.java) uses an `import jsqlite.Database;`, I will get an `Error:(6, 15) error: package jsqlite does not exist` from Android Studio.

I am trying to follow the [android-spatialite tutorial](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=spatialite-android-tutorial). The code example for this tutorial is from the eclipse era and also seems to be getting the jsqlite package in a slightly different way.

Can someone help me get on the right track here?

EDIT: My code, minus the shared objects, is on [github](https://github.com/kristina-hager/hello-world-spatialite).

Comment: What does your `AndroidManifest.xml` look like? have you added `<uses-library ...>` entries?

Comment: I tried this `<uses-library android:name="libjsqlite" android:required="true" />` in my `AndroidManifest.xml` locally, but it made no apparent difference.

Comment: The archive you linked only contains jni libs, but I think you also need a java API jar to link them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to figure this out.

Since the shared libs were already compiled, I had to keep the corresponding java file namespace at `package jsqlite;`. The real issue then was to figure out how to keep those java files actually at that top level scope.

I ended up modifying the AndroidManifest.xml for my module to not have the usual "yourcompany.packagename" scoping and instead just used "packagename".
The usual:

```
<manifest
    package="com.example.spatialite_database_driver">
</manifest>
```

becomes

```
<manifest
    package="spatialite_database_driver">
</manifest>
```

I am not sure if this is the most ideal scenario, but it lets my module work without having to get into recompiling the JNI code.

I have the process used to successfully set up this module here:
https://github.com/kristina-hager/Spatialite-Database-Driver/blob/master/README.md
along with a link to an app using the module.

*note: for this module, there are no prepared .jar or .aar files available, so I am using the shared objects + java src files in a module.*