# Native libraries (.so files) are not added to an android project

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, intellij-idea, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I'm trying to use [sqlitecipher](http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-for-android/) library which requires using native libraries. Their tutorial is very simple but it doesn't work for me. Every time I get the following error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load stlport_shared from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/org.example.test-2.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/org.example.test-2]: findLibrary returned null
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
        at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(SQLiteDatabase.java:141)
        at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(SQLiteDatabase.java:136)
```

it means .so files were not attached during compilation.

all 3 files are stored in /libs/armeabi/ directory.

I assumed that the problem is that I use maven to manage dependencies (building is performed using Android Studio anyways). The next try - include those libraries into maven dependencies. According [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/NativeLibsAsDependencies) it is pretty easy. I couldn't find them in a public repository so I used `<scope>system</scope>`
with a  tag. They were visible but it didn't work. Later found [this](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/maven-android-developers/1342a8mh4h/native-libraries-from-local-path) link where it is said that scope "system" won't work, tried adding those libraries into local repository using

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=net.sqlitecipher -DartifactId=stlport_shared -Dversion=1.0 -Dfile=libstlport_shared.so -Dpackaging=so -DgeneratePom=true
```

in the end - it didn't work.

Also I saw this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683775/include-so-library-in-apk-in-android-studio/17131418#17131418), probably this is a solution but I don't use gradle currently. Is there a way to include .so files into the apk without moving from maven to gradle?

As I understood Android Studio uses gradle internally to build apks, so all my efforts with maven are useless until they start supporting native libraries, am I right? I have also tried building the project with Intellij IDEA Cardea (13.0), unfortunately without any success.

Comment: Are the files actually in the APK?  You can use unzip to open the APK.

Comment: that's a problem - they are not in the apk. I could copy them to assets folder and then load libs from the specific folder (actually your comment helped me to realize that, thanks) but I would like to do it in the proper way. It might in the future.

Comment: The NDK is not supported in AssetStudio/gradle.  Have you tried creating the project with Eclipse or Ant? For some reason the .so files are not getting packaged. If you do decide to copy files from the assest folder make sure you use java.lang.Runtime.load and provide the full path.

Comment: Thanks, I saw this in other questions however my situation is a little bit different (I use maven). I would change code to load libraries using full path if it was my code. I could make a fork of the library and change sources then I have to spend time in the future to adopt my changes for the updated versions.

As for Eclipse - I'd rather use vim than Eclipse. No, I haven't tried building with it. I realize that the problem is in Intellij IDEA

Comment: @Frohnzie , I'll try to connect libraries through assets folder. Going to do that a bit later. If I succeed - let's find a way to give you the reward for your comment. It led me to the solution.

Comment: Seems other have found workarounds for gradle/AndroidStudio. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683775/include-so-library-in-apk-in-android-studio/17131418#17131418

Comment: if you check my question I've already referenced that topic

Comment: Well, [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/issues/detail?id=372) seems to exist atm. There's a workaround in there to manually copy the libraries from dependencies.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As soon as the native libs are in /libs/armeabi/ all you have to do is to configure the android plugin properly. Something like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
         <nativeLibrariesDirectory>${project.basedir}/libs</nativeLibrariesDirectory>
         ...
    </configuration>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helped me. I still cannot believe that I missed the "nativeLibrariesDirectory" line, it just points to the wrong directory in my case.

my workaround was to copy libraries from assets folder to a custom one (otherwise there is no path to these files) on startup and send a path to the sqlcipher so it loads copies of libraries from a custom folder (for that I needed to rewrite a calling function first). Damn, cannot believe the solution was that easy.

Comment: @ben75 will this enable you to replace or make changes to existing system libraries? Why I ask is so that these 3 files (libaudio.so, libaudioflinger.so, libaudiopolicy.so) can be replaced to enable voice_call recording from both ends of the call. Android currently has a problem with voice recording. Some devices(modified with custom roms) allow voice recording. But if we can find a way to replace these 3 files on any android device, that will be a huge break through as there are thousands of android users wanting to record phone calls, but simply can't.

Comment: @Pierre I don't think it's possible to modify system libraries without rooting your device. (this post is related to native libraries "private" to an apk/user)

Comment: @ben75  Is it possible to exclude a file in the /libs directory, by changing the configuration ?  
My question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30366514/avoid-adding-particular-native-library-files-so-to-the-project

Answer (score 1):

**To Question 1**: Yes.
I haven't had this specific problem before, but genearlly you don't need to swich to gradle. It is possible to use an ant task to add SO files to an APK. And since maven can run Ant tasks it possible.

The *nativeLibsToJar* that you found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683775/include-so-library-in-apk-in-android-studio/17131418#17131418) is nothing else than a task that puts all the SO files into a ZIP file and then uses the extension JAR instead of ZIP. You can easily do that with the [Ant task Zip](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html) (and maybe additionally [rename](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/rename.html)).

**To Question 2**: No. Because of the first answer. There is no need for "maven to support native libraries". Just use Ant as build-system.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but please take a look at ben75's answer

Comment: @Ruzard Yes, there it goes. My way here is also more the description of a hack. ben75 tell you the real way. One more day, that we go smarter to sleep than we woke up :)

Comment: @KenyakornKetsombut I agree with your comments, ant seems fine for packaging , people keep telling me to switch to gradle, I don't really want to. Ant is fine with arm64-v8a abi?? I thought maybe for that need to repackage using aapt2....

Comment: @KenyakornKetsombut to your Question 1 answer. What does zipping to .jar have to do with getting native libs into the apk? They normally just stay in libs/{abifolder} within the apk. It seems using Ant via commandline does not add native libs by default.

Comment: @KenyakornKetsombut so in theory you say i can add:                                             <zip destfile="${dist}/manual.zip"
     basedir="htdocs/manual"
     update="true"/>            to my build.xml and it will all my native lib dir to the apk

Answer (score 1):

You have to create jni folder for .so file include in android project using android studio.

I have attached image please follow these steps.

After creating jnilib folder you can put your all .so files in this folder.[image]