# Packaging .so library in maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, shared-objects

I am making a Maven project for a small Bluetooth low energy application. I am using intel's TinyB BluetoothLE library.

I've tested out the use of the library locally. In eclipse, I added TinyB's jar file to the classpath, as well as gave the location of the .so files under Build Path > configure build path > libraries > native library location.

I have followed this post: [How Do I Get SO libraries bundled in package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18495986/maven-how-do-i-get-so-libraries-bundled-in-package), but I am not sure if this applies to my situation.

Since I am very new to using Maven, I would like to ask what necessary steps I should take to ensure that I can package the TinyB .jar and .so files into my final .jar upon running Maven install?

And secondly, what steps would a consumer of my .jar need to take in order to ensure its proper use?

Comment: Yes that should work

Comment: @Acewin I'll test it out soon and see what happens