# Card.io android sdk and maven

Tags: android, maven, card.io

I'm trying to add the card.io native .so libraries to my project using maven (I can upload it on a local nexus server), however what I'm not sure about is how to go about adding the .so files and folder hirearchy. I can't seem to find any info online.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your problem correctly, I think you need to add the .so files into a folder called 'libs' and then add the line:

`<nativeLibrariesDirectory>${project.basedir}/libs</nativeLibrariesDirectory>`

in your pom file inside the `<configuration>` tag of your android-maven-plugin.

For more details, please have a look at [this similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18173341/native-libraries-so-files-are-not-added-to-an-android-project)

Answer (score 0):

Just put [install_card.io.sh](https://gist.github.com/evsinev/8596937) and [pom.xml](https://gist.github.com/evsinev/8596963) in the card.io-Android-SDK-3.1.4/libs and run install_card.io.sh in this directory.

After you can use io.card/payment in your pom.xml, all dependencies to native libraries will be automatically resolved:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.card</groupId>
    <artifactId>payment</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.4</version>
</dependency>
```