# Avoid adding particular native library files (.so) to the project

Tags: android, maven

I usually add native files to the apk using the following plugin configuration

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
         <nativeLibrariesDirectory>${project.basedir}/libs</nativeLibrariesDirectory>
         ...
    </configuration>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
</plugin>
```

Now my problem is to exclude few files ( For  example  "abc.so"  and "def.so") from adding.  Is there any way to change the configuration to solve the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no way to specify filters for `<nativeLibrariesDirectory>` but you can create another directory : `${project.basedir}/libs-filtered` and copy only the required .so files in `${project.basedir}/libs-filtered`

In plugin configuration use :

```
 <nativeLibrariesDirectory>${project.basedir}/libs-filtered</nativeLibrariesDirectory>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is a nice workaround, but in my case I can't use this solution, because other projects also using the same location to get the native files, and I'm not allowed to create a directory.