# Android Studio + dropbox-android-sync-sdk-1.1.2

Tags: android, dropbox, android-studio

Could anybody explain how I can include Dropbox SDK into Android Studio? On the dropbox's site I found information for the Eclipse IDE. I've tried include it into Android Studio, but with no result. IDE can't find the class `com.dropbox.sync`.

/*ERROR when i want create i make link mDbxAcctMgr = DbxAccountManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext(), appKey, appSecret);*/

```
    09-02 12:38:46.297    1133-1133/? E/AndroidRuntime: Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
09-02 12:38:46.307    1133-1133/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.dropbox.sync.android.CoreAccountManager.initNativeLib(CoreAccountManager.java:111)
        at com.dropbox.sync.android.CoreAccountManager.<init>(CoreAccountManager.java:91)
        at com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxAccountManager.getInstance(DbxAccountManager.java:132)
        at com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxAccountManager.getInstance(DbxAccountManager.java:100)
        at com.example.dropbox.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:43)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.dropbox.sync.android.NativeLib.<init>(NativeLib.java:33)
        at com.dropbox.sync.android.NativeLib.<clinit>(NativeLib.java:11)
        ... 18 more
        Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library DropboxSync not found
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:489)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:557)
        at com.dropbox.sync.android.NativeHttp.<clinit>(NativeHttp.java:411)
        ... 20 more
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've never used Android Studio before, so I had to look it up... these are good instructions for adding an external library to an Android Studio project: [How do I add a library project to Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio)

Following that with the Dropbox Android Sync SDK, I pasted the contents of `libs` in the Android SDK into `libs` in my Android project, and then I added this line to `build.gradle` (inside `dependencies`):

```
compile files('libs/dropbox-sync-sdk-android.jar')
```

That seemed to work for me. If you tried that and it didn't work (or if you tried something else), please provide some details.

**EDIT Pasting my answer from [Android & DropboxSync Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18574283/android-dropboxsync-library) for completeness:**

I found this SO answer helpful: [Include .so library in apk in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683775/include-so-library-in-apk-in-android-studio)

Part of my `build.gradle` file now looks like this, and my app starts successfully:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: "$buildDir/native-libs", include: 'native-libs.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

task nativeLibsToJar(
        type: Zip,
        description: 'create a jar archive of the native libs') {
    destinationDir file("$buildDir/native-libs")
    baseName 'native-libs'
    extension 'jar'
    from fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '**/*.so')
    into 'lib/'
}

tasks.withType(Compile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn(nativeLibsToJar)
}
```

Comment: Thx a lot!This line compile files('libs/dropbox-sync-sdk-android.jar') was all what i needed. I knowed what i must add some line to graddle...but which line.Now i know Thx you again!

Comment: Could you tell me, why i have errors, when i'm trying create a DbxAcccountManger? errors above

Comment: I think your new question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18574283/android-dropboxsync-library.

Answer (score 2):

The official solution didn't work for me. And I notice "Compile" in tasks.withType(Compile) has a warning of deprecated.

The following lines in build.gradle works:

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/dropbox-sync-sdk-android.jar')
}

android {
    tasks.withType(com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication) {
        pkgTask -> pkgTask.jniFolders = new HashSet<File>();
            pkgTask.jniFolders.add(new File(projectDir, 'libs'));
    }
}
```

Place the 'libs' folder from Dropbox sdk at the same level with 'build' and 'src' folder.

Answer (score 1):

You have an official answer in the Dropbox Developers Blog:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/57/using-the-sync-api-with-android-studio

It is funny that a question interesting enough to be answered by the own api developers is rated with a negative...