# Android & DropboxSync Library

Tags: java, android, dropbox

Who can help me fix error in my Android Project. I make sync with dropbox in my project, but when i try start app i have errors:  Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library DropboxSync not found

```
09-02 12:56:55.367    1313-1313/? E/AndroidRuntime: Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
09-02 12:56:55.377    1313-1313/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.dropbox.sync.android.CoreAccountManager.initNativeLib(CoreAccountManager.java:111)
        at com.dropbox.sync.android.CoreAccountManager.<init>(CoreAccountManager.java:91)
        at com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxAccountManager.getInstance(DbxAccountManager.java:132)
        at com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxAccountManager.getInstance(DbxAccountManager.java:100)
        at com.shvedchenko.skleroshop.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.dropbox.sync.android.NativeLib.<init>(NativeLib.java:33)
        at com.dropbox.sync.android.NativeLib.<clinit>(NativeLib.java:11)
        ... 18 more
        Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library DropboxSync not found
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:489)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:557)
        at com.dropbox.sync.android.NativeHttp.<clinit>(NativeHttp.java:411)
        ... 20 more
```

Line №44 is mDbxAcctMgr = DbxAccountManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext(), appKey, appSecret);

I don't understand whats wrong?

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is a general issue with native libraries and gradle. I found this SO answer helpful: [Include .so library in apk in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683775/include-so-library-in-apk-in-android-studio)

Part of my `build.gradle` file now looks like this, and my app starts successfully:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: "$buildDir/native-libs", include: 'native-libs.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

task nativeLibsToJar(
        type: Zip,
        description: 'create a jar archive of the native libs') {
    destinationDir file("$buildDir/native-libs")
    baseName 'native-libs'
    extension 'jar'
    from fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '**/*.so')
    into 'lib/'
}

tasks.withType(Compile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn(nativeLibsToJar)
}
```

Comment: Thx a lot, your post helped me!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/dropbox-sync-sdk-android.jar')
}

android {
    tasks.withType(com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication) {
        pkgTask -> pkgTask.jniFolders = new HashSet<File>();
            pkgTask.jniFolders.add(new File(projectDir, 'libs'));
    }
}
```

Place the 'libs' folder from Dropbox sdk at the same level with 'build' and 'src' folder.

Comment: @MohammadKotb Your build.gradle file

Answer (score 0):

You seem to miss the library for Dropbox (native part)

you can see that on the bottom of your stacktrace

```
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library DropboxSync not found
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:489)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:557)
    at com.dropbox.sync.android.NativeHttp.<clinit>(NativeHttp.java:411)
    ... 20 more
```

check the library download or documentation where to get the missing library file

**[UPDATE]**: How To use native libraries with android studio

Put your *.so files inside a `libs` folder beside the src folder

```
task copyNativeLibs(type: Copy) {
    from(new File('libs')) { include '**/*.so' }
    into new File(buildDir, 'native-libs')
}

tasks.withType(Compile) { compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn copyNativeLibs }

clean.dependsOn 'cleanCopyNativeLibs'

tasks.withType(com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication) { pkgTask ->
    pkgTask.jniDir new File(buildDir, 'native-libs')
}
```

Comment: I have something like that in Project/libs it SO library. For example libDropboxSync.so. But how i can explain to AndroidStudio use this object? Thx

Answer (score 0):

**solution without copying data**

Probably, most of us developers don't like to copy data from one location to another... So here's the solution without copying the .so files to your project:

```
compile files('M:\\Dropbox\\SWDevelopment\\Libraries\\Android\\dropbox-android-sync-sdk-3.1.2\\libs\\dropbox-sync-sdk-android.jar')
compile fileTree(dir: "$buildDir/native-libs", include: 'native-libs.jar')
task nativeLibsToJar(type: Zip, description: 'create a jar archive of the native libs') {
    destinationDir file("$buildDir/native-libs")
    baseName 'native-libs'
    extension 'jar'
    from fileTree(dir: 'M:/Dropbox/SWDevelopment/Libraries/Android/dropbox-android-sync-sdk-3.1.2/libs', include: '**/*.so')
    into 'lib/'
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn(nativeLibsToJar)
}
```

Just adjust the 2 occurences of my dropbox sync api folder to your own one ...