# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError in java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary from Market

Tags: loadlibrary, unsatisfiedlinkerror

by Android version
Android 2.3.3 - 2.3.7 385 65.5% 
Android 4.2 155 26.4% 
Android 4.3 28 4.8% 
Android 4.0.3 - 4.0.4 20 3.4%

1. by device
   Optimus L3 (e0) 118 20.1% 
   Xperia L (C2104) 93 15.8% 
   hsdroid 72 12.2%

   `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
   at com.android.XXX.MakeupApp.a(Unknown Source)
   at com.android.XXX.al.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
   Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load arcsoft_hairsalon from loader   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/com.android.XXX-     1.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/com.android.XXX-1]: findLibrary returned null
   at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
   at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
    at com.meiren.FlawlessFace.FlawlessFaceLib.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more`

I don't known why some devices and android version can occurs some problems!
But I test some devices(included armV6 or armV7) ,not appera this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I got same issue, and looking hard for solution. I found one, in chromium, but its not looking well. Anyway, i hope it helps you.

```
try {
        System.loadLibrary("YourLib");
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {

        System.load("YourLibPath");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using a library (arcsoft_hairsalon?) that can't be found during runtime.

We had this kind of problems before (using a haptics library in our project) that we could solve including the ".so" library not only into the *libs/* folder but also into *libs/armeabi/* and *libs/armeabi-v7a/*

Currently we are facing this issue only with the Xperia L. As soon as I find the solution I'll let you know.

I hope this helps!

**EDIT**

Have you tried this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/a/17131418/1658749 Maybe it works for you. With this solution you would be creating a bundled jar file containing the .so files. Maybe that helps (not in my case but....)

Comment: Do you have fixed this issue??

Comment: Not yet :( Sadly. Furthermore, it's happening in some other devices beyond the Xperia...so I'm still in the same point.

Comment: @user2709832 Please, read the edit, maybe it helps (I hope so)