# I've problems with "sinch app to app messaging" on my phone

Tags: android, elf, dlopen, sinch

I wanna implement sinch app to app instant messaging funcitionality to my existing app. I followed github and [tutorials](https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/android-messaging-tutorial-using-sinch-and-parse/) I added sdks to my library. I can run my app on emulator. I can login and sign up and send messaging to another account which I also created on emulator. But when I try to run my app on real phone, i've faced with problems. When I click the login and sign up button, my app has stopped. After I rerun my project on emulator, I realized that I was able to sign up on my phone. When I enter my app again, it has crushed. Briefly, my app works on emulator but not on real phone now. I need your help, please help me!!

Below is my logcat.

```
09-24 17:06:16.991  17061-17061/com.meliksah.cakir.buec E/art﹕ dlopen("/data/app/com.meliksah.cakir.buec-1/lib/arm/libsinch-android-rtc.so", RTLD_LAZY) failed: dlopen failed: "/data/app/com.meliksah.cakir.buec-1/lib/arm/libsinch-android-rtc.so" is too small to be an ELF executable: only found 0 bytes
09-24 17:06:16.991  17061-17061/com.meliksah.cakir.buec D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
09-24 17:06:16.991  17061-17061/com.meliksah.cakir.buec E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.meliksah.cakir.buec, PID: 17061
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app/com.meliksah.cakir.buec-1/lib/arm/libsinch-android-rtc.so" is too small to be an ELF executable: only found 0 bytes
            at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:371)
            at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:989)
            at com.sinch.android.rtc.internal.client.DefaultSinchClient.<clinit>(DefaultSinchClient.java:72)
            at com.sinch.android.rtc.internal.client.InternalSinchClientFactory.createSinchClient(InternalSinchClientFactory.java:17)
            at com.sinch.android.rtc.DefaultSinchClientBuilder.build(DefaultSinchClientBuilder.java:95)
            at com.meliksah.cakir.buec.MessageService.startSinchClient(MessageService.java:48)
            at com.meliksah.cakir.buec.MessageService.onStartCommand(MessageService.java:39)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3307)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:177)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1546)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

Comment: Have a look at this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285967/unsatisfiedlinkerror-android

Comment: I would suggest coding out your own solution. Trying to get sinch to work (even their tutorials) is more work than building a Google cloud messaging solution yourself. GCM is surprisingly easy, has better documentation, and lots of SO posts to help you through problems.

Answer (score 0):

This error:

```
dlopen failed: "/data/app/com.meliksah.cakir.buec-1/lib/arm/libsinch-android-rtc.so" \
is too small to be an ELF executable: only found 0 bytes
```

means that you have a zero-length file with above path.

Either you made a mistake while copying it to your phone, or something truncates it after it's copied. Fixing *that* problem is almost definitely the required first step in getting your application working.