# error "cannot locate symbol" when using System.loadLibrary

Tags: java, android, hal

I use [`System.loadLibrary`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#loadLibrary-java.lang.String-) to load a `*.so` file, but I got this error:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol 
>   "_ZN7android4base10LogMessageC1EPKcjNS0_5LogIdENS0_11LogSeverityES3_i" 
>   referenced by "/data/app/com.xx.xx- 
>   2LZ9X_IvwSNdsAL5OnmZ_w==/lib/arm64/libhidlbase.so"

What could cause this? Can you help me?

I also wrote Android source code to get vts case, and when I ran the binary test file on my phone, I also got this problem.

Comment: I tried to improve your English and your formatting, but I didn't know what you mean by "vts". Could you edit the question and explain that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnsatisfiedLinkError Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285967/unsatisfiedlinkerror-android)

Comment: vts is vendor test suite

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have not linked required target library file 'log'. You need to add the log library as linked library for your *.so file. If you are using CMake, you could add something like this to your CMakeListLists file -

```
find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
              log-lib

              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
              # you want CMake to locate.
              log )


target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       your_so_file_name

                       # Links the target library to the log library
                       # included in the NDK.
                       ${log-lib} )
```

This example is explained [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/configure-cmake.html)