# How can I link native library in Android Studio?

Tags: android, linker, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm currently using a library that I've already compiled into `.so` files. I've put the library into `jniLibs` and I load it with:

```
System.loadLibrary("library");
```

Now, I want to use this library in some of my own native code, so how can I link these `.so` files with my own native files from the `jni` folder?

Comment: Why? just #include the native code and compile the whole stuff together into 1 big .so file

Comment: I don't want to keep the whole library code into my own Git repository.

Comment: you should write another Android.mk for the other .so, specifying where the headers file of library.so can be found.

Comment: That doesn't work on Android Studio.

Comment: This is the way I've solved a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17131418/1163156

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works now in Android Studio. You can use `CFlags -I` and `ldFlags -L` when building.

Take a look at this [good example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/blob/master/hello-thirdparty/app/build.gradle).

Comment: the link doesnot exsist now please upload it gain if you have

Answer (score 0):

By "native code", I understand you want to build another C module that uses your first shared library.

You need to use the Android NDK native linking system. You can't compile your second module if it doesn't know how to get the headers of the first one, and that a shared library exists.

### The standard way

**Source code required at 2nd module compilation time.**

Use `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES`, `EXPORT_C_INCLUDES` and `LOCAL_MODULE = first-module-name` in your first shared library Android.mk

In the second module Android.mk, use `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES = libfirst-module-name`. Don't forget the "lib".

Your second module needs to know the path to the headers of your first library to use it, so you will not avoid to have the code locally when building.

Other possible solution: There is also the  `$(call import-module,<tag>)` *[[doc]](http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/IMPORT-MODULE.html)* that I've never used.

*All documentation about these compiler flags on this page: http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/ANDROID-MK.html*

### The prebuilt way

**Only .so and headers required at 2nd module compilation time**

This is fully described in [Android NDK PREBUILTS documentation.](http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/PREBUILTS.html)

First shared library:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := foo-prebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libfoo.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Second module using the first:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := foo-user
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := foo-user.c
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := foo-prebuilt
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: Android Studio does not use Android.mk files.

Comment: @dragostis over here it says there is a way to disable automated ndk-build call in Android Studio and use good old .mk files instead ; http://ph0b.com/android-studio-gradle-and-ndk-integration/