# Migrating to Android Studio including libpd

Tags: android, android-studio, migration, android-gradle-plugin, libpd

With the release of Android Studio 1.0 (AS) i want to migrate from Eclipse. Generally I need no other library then libpd (PureData) for Audio synthesis. The Problem is, that libpd for android is geared to the needs of Eclipse. So in Eclipse everything is working as expected.

The only information I could found was that: [Using libpd in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25491743/using-libpd-in-android-studio) So I know libpd and Android Studio could work together but here are maybe some other problems.

I started to generate a new simple project (MinSDK 10 - CompileSDK 21 - BuildTools 21.1.2) just with a blank activity. I can deploy this simple app to my Nexus and everything is fine.

Then I import :PDCore and :AndroidMidi as Module into my AS project and I get the Gradle build-error: *Error:The SDK Build Tools revision (17.0.0) is too low for project ':PdCore'. Minimum required is 19.1.0*

I installed API 19 and Build Tools version 19.1 via the SDK Manager but that's not solving my problem.
I changed the buildToolsVersion of the apps build.gradle file to "19.1.0" but that's not solving my problem.

Any advices to get Gradle working probably? 
Maybe anyone got a sample Android Studio project with libpd to share?

Thanks in advance!

FYI: I wrote some posts regarding migrating to Android Studio using libpd. Take a look here:

- http://www.journal.deviantdev.com/using-libpd-with-android-studio/
- http://www.journal.deviantdev.com/update-using-libpd-with-android-studio/
- http://www.journal.deviantdev.com/sample-libpd-android-studio/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change the build.gradle of the :PDCore and :AndroidMidi modules. At the moment they are using 17, update the BuildTools to the newest version (21.1.2). This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I created a fork of the libpd-for-android and migrated it to Android Studio. You can clone it and open it in Android Studio as a 'Non Android Studio Project'. This worked very nicely for me and you can also now created an .aar file and use it in your Android App ( instead of copying the whole code or using git submodules):

https://github.com/tkirshboim/pd-for-android