# Android Studio "Current NDK support is deprecated"

Tags: android, c++, build, gradle, android-ndk

As of Jan 2015 the NDK support for Android studio is still unusable.
A cryptic message says: "Alternative will be provided in the future."

I'd like to know what's gradle/google direction on this is since it's impossible to plan a proper development plan at the moment.

Version 0.7+: They suggested to still use ndk-build / ant
Version 0.8+: They've introduced a minimal NDK support
Version 1.0.0: It looked like NDK support was going to be official
Version 1.0.2: It now looks like NDK support is deprecated.

My questions are:

- Is everyone reverting to ndk-build and hand made android.mk files?
- Is anyone using the currently deprecated method on 1.0.0+ (gradle ndk support) on a serious size project?
- What sort of direction the "Alternative will be provided in the future" would go? Is is possible for any insider to answer that without breaking any company rules?

Edit: it's not a duplicate because it was referring to the evolution of Android Studio and NDK, the other question refers to a very ancient version of Android Studio as I've detailed in my post the NDK support has changed drastically from version to version without a clear direction, up to now with the release of 1.3

Comment: http://ph0b.com/android-studio-gradle-and-ndk-integration/

Comment: Thanks I've seen that link already but it didn't answer any of my questions unfortunately.

Comment: "NDK support for Android studio is still unusable" it is just a warning, are you having other problems that make it unusable?

Comment: Here's a bit of 'official' word about gradle+ndk: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82187

Comment: Android Studio 1.3 at Canary channel fully supports NDK now. Reference: http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/latest

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android studio, gradle and NDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667903/android-studio-gradle-and-ndk)

Comment: June 18th, 2015: Android Studio 1.3 Beta is now available in the beta channel! Sorry, this build does not yet contain the C/C++ support;
source: http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio13betaavailable

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28174893/android-studio-current-ndk-support-is-deprecated

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Update from Google I/O 2015

> Android Studio v1.3 Preview - We are releasing a new version of Android
>   Studio. Most notable is a much requested feature from our Android **NDK**
>   & game developers: **code editing and debugging for C/C++ code**. Based on
>   JetBrains Clion platform, the Android Studio NDK plugin provides
>   features such as **refactoring and code completion** for C/C++ code
>   alongside your Java code. Java and C/C++ code support is integrated
>   into one development experience free of charge for Android app
>   developers. **Update to Android Studio v1.3 via the Canary channel** and
>   let us know what you think.

Source from android developers blog [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-m-developer-preview-tools.html).

---

### **New Update 30/7/2015 -> Android Studio v1.3 Released**

> As a part of the Android 1.3 stable release, we included an Early
>   Access Preview of the C++ editor & debugger support paired with an
>   experimental build plugin. See the Android C++ Preview page for
>   information on how to get started. Support for more complex projects
>   and build configurations is in development.
>   [image]

Quoted from android developers blog [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/07/get-your-hands-on-android-studio-13.html).

**Added Features**:

- Code completion
- Code navigation (go to declaration, jump between header and
  implementation, etc)
- Quick fixes
- Intentions
- Refactoring
- Source format
- Debugging
- ...

**For steps on how to use it, look [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/android-ndk-preview).**

Answer (score 8):

I invoke the command line, not sure where I got this from, it's basically your first option, reverting to `ndk-build` with hand made `android.mk`. Fine if you don't want to control ndk abiFilters by product flavour.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion

        ndk {
            moduleName "glues"
        }
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs' //set .so files location to libs
        jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
    }

    task buildNative(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK') {
        def ndkDir = android.ndkDirectory
        commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build",
                '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath, // Change src/main/jni the relative path to your jni source
                '-j', Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors(),
                'all',
                'NDK_DEBUG=1'
    }

    task cleanNative(type: Exec, description: 'Clean JNI object files') {
        def ndkDir = android.ndkDirectory
        commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build",
                '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath, // Change src/main/jni the relative path to your jni source
                'clean'
    }

    clean.dependsOn 'cleanNative'

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn buildNative
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
}
```

I only see those warnings if I setup `abiFilter` on the `productFlavors`:

```
productFlavors {
    x86 {
        ndk {
            abiFilter "x86"
        }
    }
    mips {
        ndk {
            abiFilter "mips"
        }
    }
    armv7 {
        ndk {
            abiFilter "armeabi-v7a"
        }
    }
    arm {
        ndk {
            abiFilter "armeabi"
        }
    }
    fat
}
```

Note, older gradle plugin versions used `android.plugin.ndkFolder` rather than `android.ndkDirectory`. For more info, see: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-to-1-0-0

Comment: Thanks @JoeBowbeer for edit suggestion. It got rejected by others, but I put comment at bottom and as soon as I can verify myself I'll incorporate edit myself.

Comment: So I've just seen you work for google @JoeBowbeer and mainly answer android questions. I think I'll apply your edit first and verify later! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

NDK will be fully supported since Android Studio 1.3, including native debugging.

Comment: Yes, I also got this yesterday from Google I/O 2015. Great!

Comment: @bmaupin, sorry, my bad. The original link I've got the news from is this: "Today, Google has announced Android Studio 1.3, a new version of the IDE with built-in support for the NDK. Google says the plugin is based on the JetBrains CLion platform and that it will be available free of charge to all Android developers." (http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2015/05/good-news-for-game-devs-android-studio-1-3-supports-androids-cc-ndk/)

Answer (score 0):

```
android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

in your gradle.properties