# Android NDK creating executable but not pushing it on the device (Eclipse)

Tags: android, c, eclipse, android-ndk, cross-compiling

Hello I use Android NDK on Eclipse (Windows) to compile a C program (needed by my Android app).
The file is compiled and the executable is created in libs/armeabi folder of my Android project, but when I run the app on the device, there's no trace of it.

The executable is fine, in fact if I rename it to libmyapp.so it's pushed correctly to /data/data/myapp/lib on the device.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean "there's no trace of it."? You know it should be inside the APK. Do your NDK calls fail or work?

Comment: Also I wouldn't use eclipse long term. Look to move to Android Studio ASAP. NDK takes some setting up, but all the help you need is here on SO, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30641567/360211

Comment: NDK call succeds, the executable is created but not pushed on the device.
If I choose BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY instead of BUILD_EXECUTABLE, for example, libmyapp.so file is not only created in libs/armeabi in my project but also pushed in /data/data/myapp/lib folder on the device.

Comment: You should be creating a .so library and calling it from java. Not creating an executable.

Comment: Perhaps you can explain why you are creating an executable and not a library.

Comment: it's a command line tool.

Comment: But that's because you've compiled it as such. You could easily have a NDK method that invoked the same code as your Main method.

Comment: Ok I'll try to change it to a library.

Comment: About Android Studio, I've already thought about moving to it but I'm in the middle of a project so I postponed the move to after project's deadline.

Comment: I recommend familiarizing yourself with https://developer.android.com/ndk/samples/sample_hellojni.html first and then you might be able to easily see how you can invoke your existing code as a library call.

Comment: You also may want it to run on ARM, Intel etc, Well as a NDK library that's as simple as telling it to compile for all targets. One line.

Answer (score 0):

If you build an *executable*, a command-line tool, it is up to you to install it on the device and make sure it's in the path. If you want to automate installation, you have two options:

1) write a script that would run on a PC (linux/windows/mac) and install your executable via `adb`.

2) write an Android GUI application, place the executable in its assets/ folder, and have the application unpack and install it on the first launch.