# How can I access sdk/ndk paths in my gradle build scripts?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

In Android Studio 1.3.2, I have set `sdk.dir` and `ndk.dir` set in `local.properties`, but how can I access them within my gradle build scripts?

What I want to do is call ndk-build manually without having to hard code a path to the ndk-build, which now is in a known location at `sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build`. Are these path variables exposed, or, how can I expose them?

Answer (score 6):

You can get the ndk.dir by android.ndkDirectory. Look at this answer to see how you can call ndk-build from gradle: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28566337/3836816

Comment: Thanks, I'll play with that. In my first stab it didn't seem to work with Gradle 2.5 experimental / Android Studio 1.3.2 but I will keep trying.