# Android Studio: how to push libraries to GitHub

Tags: git, github, android-studio

I am looking for a solution for the following problem, I have been looking around and I only found resources on how to use libraries in Github.

The problem is the following:

I have an Android Studio project that contains both java libraries and native libraries (to add native libraries I followed the advice in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17131418/1815311) answer)

The libraries I am using are not available anywhere online (I am using the Zlib Qr Code library)
so I want to push them to Github...

Please do you know how to do it?

Comment: What does `git status` show?

Answer (score 1):

GitHub is a source version control system and not very suitable for binaries. Please consider using a proper binary repository for that purpose. I recommend you look at [Bintray](http://bintray.com). It's a very easy to upload the libraries to and to consume them from Gradle.