# Include Pre-compiled Static LIbrary using NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-studio

I am looking to include a static library that is pre-compiled in my Android Studio NDK project. I am using Android Studio 1.0.1, and any solutions that attempt this problem on SO seem outdated (or involves creating a library project and including it).

The structure is as follows:

```
app
/--src
/--main
/--java
+--jni
+--jniLibs
   /--armeabi
       /--libpng.a
    --armeabiv7
       /--libpng.a
    ...(for each abi)
```

I am attempting to include the library libpng. I tried creating jniLibs (as per [ph0b](http://ph0b.com/android-studio-gradle-and-ndk-integration/) (awesome guide, btw) and adding libpng.a to the respective ABI folder. This still gives me the error - *cannot find -llibpng* when I try to compile with the below code:

```
ndk {
        moduleName "game" 
        cFlags "-std=c++11 -fexceptions -DANDROID -I${project.buildDir}/../src/main/jni/include \
                -I${project.buildDir}/../src/main/jni/include/png"
        ldLibs "EGL", "GLESv3", "dl", "log", "android", "libpng"
        stl "gnustl_static"
}
```

Comment: have u tried just "png" in your ndk.ldLibs expression . ie dont include the prefix 'lib'.

Comment: @RobertRowntree yes :( have tried that one. Have also tried adding libpng to the corresponding platform in ndk/platforms/android-21/usr/lib as a last ditch effort. Have tried .so and .a, to no avail. The only thing that works, is taking ALL the source files for libpng and sticking them in a directory and including it in my jni.srcDirs.... is super messy, clunky, and takes over a minute to build now.

Comment: i still use ph0b technique for NDK where you override the NDK plugin  using your own 'sourceSets.main' to overide the framework...            jni.srcDirs = [] /*disable automatic ndk-build call */
            jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'  if i dont change actuall cpp source files it does NOT increase build time at all and uses my own Android.mk file as per ph0b

Comment: That's what I'm in the process of doing now, is switching over to ph0b's setup. From what I can garner after hours of reading, I just don't think Android Studio supports what I need, yet. Thanks for the input!

Comment: http://ph0b.com/android-studio-gradle-and-ndk-integration/  if u have not already.. dont forget to get the latest NDK. ( 10c )

Answer (score 3):

This now works properly via the experimental plugin.

For a full description, see [this whole excellent article](http://ph0b.com/new-android-studio-ndk-support/), which is where I'm taking this from, but I am also using it myself and it works.

This is my `build.gradle` - note that in my case it's for a library project, and I'm using static links rather than shared.

```
buildscript {
    dependencies
            {
                classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.7.0-alpha3"
            }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.library'

model {
    repositories {
        libs(PrebuiltLibraries) {
            v8_base {
                binaries.withType(StaticLibraryBinary) {
                    staticLibraryFile = file("src/main/jni/libs/${targetPlatform.getName()}/libv8_base.a")
                }
            }
            v8_libbase {
                binaries.withType(StaticLibraryBinary) {
                    staticLibraryFile = file("src/main/jni/libs/${targetPlatform.getName()}/libv8_libbase.a")
                }
            }
            v8_libplatform {
                binaries.withType(StaticLibraryBinary) {
                    staticLibraryFile = file("src/main/jni/libs/${targetPlatform.getName()}/libv8_libplatform.a")
                }
            }
            v8_nosnapshot {
                binaries.withType(StaticLibraryBinary) {
                    staticLibraryFile = file("src/main/jni/libs/${targetPlatform.getName()}/libv8_nosnapshot.a")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    android {

        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

        sources {
            main {
                jni {
                    source {
                        srcDir "src/main/jni"
                    }
                    dependencies {
                        library "v8_base" linkage "static"
                        library "v8_libbase" linkage "static"
                        library "v8_libplatform" linkage "static"
                        library "v8_nosnapshot" linkage "static"
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        ndk {
            moduleName "v8example"
            cppFlags.add("-std=c++11")
            cppFlags.add("-I${file("src/main/jni/include")}".toString())
            cppFlags.add("-fexceptions")
            ldLibs.add("log")
            stl "stlport_static"
            abiFilters.add("armeabi armeabi-v7a x86")
        }
    }
}
```

The alternative is that you use the old Gradle approach of calling ndkBuild yourself, thus using the `.mk` files. That also works fine but you lose the nice integration with Android Studio, e.g. your `jni` files showing up appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

**Adding .so Library in Android Studio 1.0.2**

1. Create Folder "jniLibs" inside "src/main/"
2. Put all your .so libraries inside "src/main/jniLibs" folder
3. Folder structure looks like,

   |--app:

   |--|--src:

   |--|--|--main

   |--|--|--|--jniLibs

   |--|--|--|--|--armeabi

   |--|--|--|--|--|--.so Files
4. No extra code requires just sync your project and run your application.

   **Reference**

   https://github.com/commonsguy/sqlcipher-gradle/tree/master/src/main

Comment: I've done that with .a-files (static libraries), but what now? How can I use classes and functions declared within this libraries in my java code?

Answer (score 1):

As ndk support is now limited in gradle, you could try this for static libraries of different abi.

```
    ndk {
        moduleName "game" 
        ....
        ldLibs ..., file(projectDir).absolutePath+"/src/main/jniLibs/\$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libpng.a"
        ....
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you cannot just include the .so files, you also need to have the src folders that actually provide the interface to access the methods in those .so files. I would recommend against coupling your project to the library that way.

The best way is to include it as a library module from android studio and discard the jni folders to disable ndkbuild and point the jnilib to the /libs folder by adding following to the build.gradle file

```
jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
jniLibs.srcDirs = [ 'libs' ] //no need to copy the .so files from /libs to /jniLibs folder
```

(check that the libs directory has also been imported correctly by android studio with .so files)

importing the library as a module takes care of following automatically

> a)*yourlibrary* library folder in your project folder and restructured according to gradle convention 
>   b)imported the project(include ':*yourlibrary*' in settings.gradle) and
>   c)created the dependencies (“File -> Project Structure -> Select main app module from the left subwindow -> Dependencies (last tab) -> Press the green “+” on your right -> *yourlibrary* as Module Dependency -> OK”)

Answer (score 0):

This is really ugly, but it works! You can trick Gradle into allowing you to inject code into the generated Android.mk file:

```
    ndk {
        abiFilter "armeabi-v7a"

        // We need to inject the static library into the
        // NDK build, and Gradle doesn't offer a way to directly
        // modify the Android.mk file... So we hack it!
        //
        // You can see the end result at:
        //   build/intermediates/ndk/debug/Android.mk

        moduleName "This_is_a_terrible_Gradle_hack\n" +

        "include \$(CLEAR_VARS)\n" +

        "LOCAL_MODULE := mystaticlib_prebuilt\n" +
        "LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := mystaticlib/include\n" +
        "LOCAL_SRC_FILES := mystaticlib/libmystaticlib.a\n" +

        "include \$(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)\n" +

        "include \$(CLEAR_VARS)\n" +
        "LOCAL_MODULE := MyActualModule\n" +
        "LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += mystaticlib_prebuilt"

        cFlags "-std=c++11 -fexceptions -frtti -pthread"
        stl "gnustl_shared"
        ldLibs "log", "OpenSLES", "z"
    }
```

Comment: *sigh* damn NDK support.

Do you have the folder structure so static lib is found?

Comment: @MLProgrammer-CiM did you ever figure out the folder structure?

Comment: Nah, I went for Plan B, kind of like this: https://gist.github.com/eleventigers/e112fd76dd95e8e8ff5b