# Using .a libraries with Android Studio

Tags: android, static-libraries, pjsip

I downloaded and build the libraries from [pjSIP](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android#Requirements) for Android.
It generated some static libraries (.a-files, 19 of them, to be precise), and I implemented them in my project, following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27532062/android-studio-include-pre-compiled-static-library-using-ndk). My project structure
looks like this now:

[image]

```
|--app:
|--|--src:
|--|--|--main
|--|--|--|--jniLibs
|--|--|--|--|--armeabi
|--|--|--|--|--|--.a Files
```

I would like to use classes and methods within this libraries now,
as an example, I would like to use the examples shown [here in the pjSIP documentation](http://www.pjsip.org/docs/book-latest/html/endpoint.html) in Java. For example:

```
Endpoint ep = new Endpoint();
```

How can I achieve this, what am I missing here?

Comment: Since I am pretty new here, I would apreachiate to know whats wrong with my question instead of simply getting downvoted :/

Comment: I do not know why the downvote, Android studio does not have support NDK, if you need  build the code you must to use the eclipse.

Comment: Do you have any good tutorial on how to do this? I am pretty new on working with libraries, have never done this before.

Comment: See here : https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/android/Android_NDK.html