# Developing native C++ Application in Android Studio 1.5 using OpenCV 3.1

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

I am currently working through "OpenCV Android Programming By Example" by Amgad Muhammad.

In chapter 6 the user is supposed to develop a panoramic viewer. I stuck in this chapter for about two weeks now and still facing errors when trying to sync the project. I've tried several other code adjustements, experimental-gradle-versions etc. but none of it worked.

This is my current build.gradle(project):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.4.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and this my build.gradle(module):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'
model {
android {
    compileSdkVersion = 23
    buildToolsVersion = "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig.with {
        applicationId = "com.example.moritz.ndktest"
        minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 11
        targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
    }
}

android.ndk {
    moduleName = "Pano"
    ldLibs += ['log']
    cppFlags.add("-std=c++11") // Add provisions to allow C++11 functionality
    cppFlags.add("-fexceptions")
    cppFlags.add("-I${file("D:/Android/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include")}".toString())
    //cppFlags += "-I${file("D:/Android/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include/opencv")}".toString()
    ldLibs.addAll(["android", "EGL", "GLESv2", "dl", "log", "z"])
    stl = "gnustl_shared"
}

/*android.sources {
    main {
        jni {
            source {
                srcDir 'src/main/jni'
            }
        }
    }
}*/

android.buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled = false
        proguardFiles.add(file("proguard-rules.txt"))
    }
}

android.productFlavors {
    create("arm") {
        ndk.with{
            abiFilters.add("armeabi")

            File curDir = file('./')
            curDir = file(curDir.absolutePath)
            String libsDir = curDir.absolutePath + "\\src\\main\\jniLibs\\armeabi\\"

            ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_core.a")
            ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_highgui.a")
            ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_imgproc.a")
            ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_java3.so")
            ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_ml.a")

        }
    }
    create("armv7") {
        ndk.with {
            abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")

            File curDir = file('./')
            curDir = file(curDir.absolutePath)
            String libsDir = curDir.absolutePath + "\\src\\main\\jniLibs\\armeabi-v7a\\"
            ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_core.a")
            ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_highgui.a")
            ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_imgproc.a")
            ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_java3.so")
            ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_ml.a")
            ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_ts.a")

        }
    }
}
android.sources{
    main{
        jni{
            source{
                srcDirs += ['src/main/jni']
            }
        }
    }
}
} dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
//compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
compile project(':openCVLibrary310')
}
```

and this my build.gradle(opencv310):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.library'
model{
android {
    compileSdkVersion = 23
    buildToolsVersion = "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 11
        targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
    }
}

android.buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles.add(file("proguard-rules.txt"))
    }
}
}
```

in gradle.porperties I have:

```
android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

and my gradle-wrapper.properties looks like:

```
#Mon Apr 04 13:55:17 CEST 2016
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.8-all.zip
```

The error I get right now:

> Error:Unable to load class 'com.android.build.gradle.managed.NdkConfig_Impl'.
>   Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
>
> - Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
>     Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
> - The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
>     Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
> - Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

Thanks in advance!!!

**EDIT:**
I changed my classpath in build.gradle (project) to:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.6.0-alpha5'
```

and therefore my gradle-wrapper.properties to:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

(in *Settings/Build, Excecution, Deployment/Gradle* I've selected "Use default gradle wrapper" btw.)

and my buildToolsVersion to 23.0.1 and it seems that I made a step forward but now I am facing a bunch of new errors:

> D:\Android\AndroidStudioProjects\NDKtest\app\src\main\jni\Pano.cpp
>   Error:(16, 44) error: no matching function for call to 'cv::FastFeatureDetector::FastFeatureDetector(int)'
>   Information:(16, 44) candidates are:
>   In file included from D:\Android\AndroidStudioProjects\NDKtest\app\src\main\jni\Pano.cpp:4:0:
>   D:\Android\OpenCV-android-sdk\sdk\native\jni\include/opencv2/features2d.hpp:411:20: note: cv::FastFeatureDetector::FastFeatureDetector()
>   Error:(57, 9) error: 'OrbFeatureDetector' is not a member of 'cv'
>   Error:(58, 9) error: 'detector' was not declared in this scope
>   Error:(80, 48) error: no matching function for call to 'cv::FastFeatureDetector::FastFeatureDetector(int)'
>   Information:(80, 48) candidates are:
>   In file included from D:\Android\AndroidStudioProjects\NDKtest\app\src\main\jni\Pano.cpp:4:0:
>   D:\Android\OpenCV-android-sdk\sdk\native\jni\include/opencv2/features2d.hpp:411:20: note: cv::FastFeatureDetector::FastFeatureDetector()
>   Error:(86, 13) error: 'OrbFeatureDetector' is not a member of 'cv'
>   Error:(87, 13) error: 'detector' was not declared in this scope
>   Error:(93, 13) error: 'OrbDescriptorExtractor' is not a member of 'cv'
>   Error:(94, 13) error: 'descriptor' was not declared in this scope
>   Error:(99, 13) error: 'BriefDescriptorExtractor' is not a member of 'cv'
>   Error:(100, 13) error: 'descriptor' was not declared in this scope
>   Error:(111, 13) error: 'FREAK' is not a member of 'cv'
>   Error:(112, 13) error: 'descriptor' was not declared in this scope
>                descriptor.compute(grayObject,objectKeyPoints,objectDescriptor);
>                ^
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compilePanoArmeabiDebugArmSharedLibraryPanoMainCpp'.
>   A build operation failed.
>         C++ compiler failed while compiling Pano.cpp.
>     See the complete log at: file:///D:/Android/AndroidStudioProjects/NDKtest/app/build/tmp/compilePanoArmeabiDebugArmSharedLibraryPanoMainCpp/output.txt

My Pano.cpp:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d.hpp>
#include <vector>

extern "C" {

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_app3_pano_PanoActivity_FindFastFeatures(JNIEnv*, jobject, jlong addrGray, jlong addrRgba)
{
    cv::Mat& mGr  = *(cv::Mat*)addrGray;
    cv::Mat& mRgb = *(cv::Mat*)addrRgba;
    std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> v;

    cv::FastFeatureDetector detector(50);
    detector.detect(mGr, v);
    for( unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++ )
    {
        const cv::KeyPoint& kp = v[i];
        cv::circle(mRgb, cv::Point(kp.pt.x, kp.pt.y), 10, cv::Scalar(255,0,0,255));
    }
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_app3_pano_PanoActivity_FindHarrisCorners(JNIEnv*, jobject, jlong addrGray, jlong addrRgba)
{
    cv::Mat& mGr  = *(cv::Mat*)addrGray;
    cv::Mat& mRgb = *(cv::Mat*)addrRgba;
    cv::Mat dst_norm;
    cv::Mat dst = cv::Mat::zeros(mGr.size(),CV_32FC1);
    int blockSize = 2;
    int apertureSize = 3;
    double k = 0.04;
    float threshold=150;

    cv::cornerHarris( mGr, dst, blockSize, apertureSize, k, cv::BORDER_DEFAULT );
    cv::normalize( dst, dst_norm, 0, 255, cv::NORM_MINMAX, CV_32FC1, cv::Mat() );

    for( unsigned int i = 0; i < dst_norm.rows; i++ )
    {
        float * row=dst_norm.ptr<float>(i);
        for(int j=0;j<dst_norm.cols;j++)
        {
            if(row[j]>=threshold)
            {
                cv::circle(mRgb, cv::Point(j, i), 10, cv::Scalar(255,0,0,255));
            }
        }
    }
}
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_app3_pano_PanoActivity_FindORBFeatures(JNIEnv*, jobject, jlong addrRgba, jint featuresNumber)
{
    cv::Mat& mRgb = *(cv::Mat*)addrRgba;
    cv::Mat grayImg;
    std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> v;
    cv::cvtColor(mRgb,grayImg,cv::COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);
    cv::OrbFeatureDetector detector(featuresNumber);
    detector.detect(grayImg, v);
    cv::drawKeypoints(grayImg,v,mRgb,cv::Scalar::all(-1),cv::DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS);
}
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_app3_pano_PanoActivity_FindMatches(JNIEnv*, jobject, jlong objectAddress, jlong sceneAddress,jint detectorID, jint descriptorID,jlong matchingResult)
{
    cv::Mat& object  = *(cv::Mat*)objectAddress;
    cv::Mat& scene = *(cv::Mat*)sceneAddress;
    cv::Mat& result = *(cv::Mat*)matchingResult;

    cv::Mat grayObject;
    cv::Mat grayScene;
    cv::cvtColor(object,grayObject,cv::COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);
    cv::cvtColor(scene,grayScene,cv::COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);

    std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> objectKeyPoints;
    std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> sceneKeyPoints;

    cv::Mat objectDescriptor;
    cv::Mat scenceDescriptor;

    if(detectorID==1)//FAST
    {
        cv::FastFeatureDetector detector(50);
        detector.detect(grayObject, objectKeyPoints);
        detector.detect(grayScene, sceneKeyPoints);
    }
    else if(detectorID==5)//ORB
    {
        cv::OrbFeatureDetector detector;
        detector.detect(grayObject, objectKeyPoints);
        detector.detect(grayScene, sceneKeyPoints);
    }

    if(descriptorID==3)//ORB
    {
        cv::OrbDescriptorExtractor descriptor;
        descriptor.compute(grayObject,objectKeyPoints,objectDescriptor);
        descriptor.compute(grayScene,sceneKeyPoints,scenceDescriptor);
    }
    else if(descriptorID==4)//BRIEF
    {
        cv::BriefDescriptorExtractor descriptor;
        descriptor.compute(grayObject,objectKeyPoints,objectDescriptor);
        descriptor.compute(grayScene,sceneKeyPoints,scenceDescriptor);
    }
    else if(descriptorID==5)//BRISK
    {
        cv::BRISK descriptor;
        descriptor.compute(grayObject,objectKeyPoints,objectDescriptor);
        descriptor.compute(grayScene,sceneKeyPoints,scenceDescriptor);
    }
    else if(descriptorID==6)//FREAK
    {
        cv::FREAK descriptor;
        descriptor.compute(grayObject,objectKeyPoints,objectDescriptor);
        descriptor.compute(grayScene,sceneKeyPoints,scenceDescriptor);
    }

    cv::BFMatcher matcher(cv::NORM_HAMMING);
    std::vector< cv::DMatch > matches;
    matcher.match( objectDescriptor, scenceDescriptor, matches);

    double min_dist = 100;
    for( int i = 0; i < objectDescriptor.rows; i++ )
    {
        double dist = matches[i].distance;
        if( dist < min_dist ) min_dist = dist;
    }
    std::vector< cv::DMatch > good_matches;
    for( int i = 0; i < objectDescriptor.rows; i++ )
    {
        if( matches[i].distance <= 3*min_dist )
        {
            good_matches.push_back( matches[i]);
        }
    }
    drawMatches( grayObject, objectKeyPoints, grayScene, sceneKeyPoints,good_matches, result, cv::Scalar::all(-1), cv::Scalar::all(-1),
                 std::vector<char>(),
                 cv::DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS+cv::DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS);

}
}
```

So it seems like my linking to my opencv-include-folder in my build.gradle(module) via cppFlags.add() does not work properly. But I really don't know what's wrong with it?

Developing Environment:

- Windows 10 (x64)
- Android Studio 1.5.1
- jdk1.8.0_73
- ndk-r11b
- OpenCV-3-1-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, I'm working through this book too. The code in this book work in older version of Opencv (2.4). You need to read the reference of Opencv 3.1.0 because some class(such as `FastFeatureDetector`, `OrbFeatureDetecture`,..) have changed. My `FindFastFeature` and ORB function :

p/s: Don't just copy the code, you should modify it and go through the functions one by one.

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_hieuvecto_softscanner2_MainActivity_FindFastFeatures(JNIEnv*, jobject, jlong addrGray, jlong addrRgba){
    cv::Mat& mGr = *(cv::Mat*)addrGray;
    cv::Mat& mRgb = *(cv::Mat*)addrRgba;
    std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> v;
    cv::Ptr<cv::FeatureDetector> detector = cv::FastFeatureDetector::create(50);
    detector->detect(mGr, v);
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<v.size(); i++) {
        const cv::KeyPoint& kp = v[i];
        cv::circle(mRgb, cv::Point(kp.pt.x, kp.pt.y), 10, cv::Scalar(255,0,0,255));
    }
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_hieuvecto_softscanner2_MainActivity_OrbFeaturesDetector(JNIEnv*, jobject, jlong addrRgba, jint featuresNumber) {
    cv::Mat& mRgb = *(cv::Mat*)addrRgba;
    cv::Mat grayImg;
    std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> v;
    cv::cvtColor(mRgb, grayImg, cv::COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);
    cv::Ptr<cv::FeatureDetector> detector = cv::ORB::create(featuresNumber);
    detector->detect(grayImg, v);
    cv::drawKeypoints(grayImg,v,mRgb,cv::Scalar::all(-1),cv::DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS);
}
```

And My build.gradle of app module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.3"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "com.hieuvecto.softscanner2"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 15
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
            versionCode = 1
            versionName = "1.0"
        }
    }

    //Make  sure    to  build   with    JDK version 7


    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            // minifyEnabled = false
            // proguardFiles = getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    android.ndk {
        moduleName = "Pano"
        cppFlags.add("-I${file("D:/download/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include")}".toString())
        cppFlags.add("-std=c++11")
        cppFlags.add("-frtti")
        cppFlags.add("-fexceptions")
        ldLibs.addAll(["log", "opencv_java3"])
        stl    = "gnustl_static"
    }

    android.productFlavors {
        create("arm") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi")
            ndk.ldFlags.add("-L${file('src/main/jniLibs/armeabi')}".toString())
        }
        create("arm7") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")
            ndk.ldFlags.add("-L${file('src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a')}".toString())
        }
        create("arm8") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("arm64-v8a")
            ndk.ldFlags.add("-L${file('src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a')}".toString())
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':openCVLibrary310')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you use static libraries, but you don't prebuild them.
Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27532062/include-pre-compiled-static-library-using-ndk) out.

Comment: Okay, I tried this now (new build.gradle: http://codepad.org/UP9a1AjV ) but the error stays the same. May there be something wrong with my paths? 
I've uploaded an image of my project-structure: http://fs5.directupload.net/images/160406/8g2jpyi4.jpg To be honest this whole gradle-ndk-stuff is really confusing for me but I urgently need to get this working! :-s

Comment: First of all. Have you tried to clean your project?

Comment: If you mean by _Build/Clean Project_ then yes, periodically.

Comment: Then. You wrote `ocv_java3{
                binaries.withType(StaticLibraryBinary) {
                    staticLibraryFile = file("src/main/jniLibs/${targetPlatform.getName()}/libopencv_java3.so")
                }
            }` but it's **shared**, not static

Comment: Secondly. Why do you link `libopencv_ts.a` with armv7, but not just arm?

Comment: Is it really `lblibs.addAll(OPENCV_STATIC_LIBS)`or `iDlibs.addAll()`?

And it says **Error:Attempt to read a write only view of model of type 'java.lang.Object' given to rule 'android.productFlavors { ... } @ app\build.gradle line 94, column 5'** which is this part `android.productFlavors {
        APP_ABIS.each { abi ->
            create(getFlavorName(abi)) {
                ...
}`

Comment: Oh, excuse me. Of course **ldLibs** - I don't have android studio to check syntax. But it's sort of direction.

Comment: I've mistaken - in **ocv_java3** block it should be **sharedLibraryFile** instead of static

Comment: Actually, **ocv_java3** is already **shared** (as it was in your code). The rest is **static**.

Comment: **repositories::libs::ocv_java3** block; at the begining

Comment: Not sure if I got you but I inserted it in `android.sources{ main{ jni{ dependencies{ ... library "repositories::libs::ocv_java3" linkage "shared"}...` which unfortunately didn't had any effect.

Comment: Oh. You're doing it totally wrong. Be more patient and attentive. Don't just copy and paste try to understand what is going on. I've made a [version with several corrections] (http://pastebin.com/mRxxjSEA)

Comment: I try man, I really try. But it's hard if there is so much which I don't understand.^^ Can you tell me where excactly the difference in your new version is? I couldn't find the **repositories::libs::ocv_java3**-part and the error is still the same. :(

Comment: It is not literally **repositories::libs::ocv_java3** it is `model { repositories { libs(PrebuiltLibraries) {  ocv_java3{ ...` I just wrote it in c++ notation

Comment: I see. But what was the change then?

Comment: staticLibraryFile = file("src/main/jniLibs/${targetPlatform.getName()}/libopencv_java3.so") to sharedLibraryFile = file("src/main/jniLibs/${targetPlatform.getName()}/libopencv_java3.so")

Comment: Okay. But as I already said, the error is still the same, unfortunately.

**Gradle 'NDKtest' project refresh failed. Error:Attempt to read a write only view of model of type 'java.lang.Object' given to rule 'android.productFlavors { ... } @ app\build.gradle line 94, column 5'**

Comment: I also saw, you have more static libraries in your **jniLibs** folder, then you try to link. Or could you create a repo somewhere? I could take a look at your code.

Comment: Check your pull requests.

Comment: Okay, I merged it. And finally, there is no more compiling error. 

But: When I try to run the app now on my mobile, it starts for a second and then crashes. Logcat said: **java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: (...)couldn't find "libPano.so"** so I added the libPano.so from the book-example-code to every directory within jniLibs, but then the error is: **dlopen failed: could not load library "libopencv_java.so" needed by "libPano.so"; caused by library "libopencv_java.so" not found**

Comment: *Sigh* Moritz, I have a feeling, you haven't read anything about ndk. You just try to copy and paste everything was written without even trying to understand, what it is and how it works. Please, try to read android manuals, tutorials etc. I haven't seen your java part and i'm not going to do this. You had a question about compile problems - now they are gone. The work I've done - is a solution, that could be improved, where you can add abis, other libraries etc. I'm **sure** that there's an answer at stackoverflow on dlopen issue. Please, don't make me google it for you.

Comment: You're completely right. I am sorry! Thank you very very much for your help and your patience so far.