# Facebook Conceal crypto for android is always unavailable

Tags: android, encryption

I'm not able to use [Facebook Conceal](https://facebook.github.io/conceal/documentation/) Libraries in my android application. The `crypto` always seems to return true on `crypto.isAvailable()`.
Also, I'm using Android 1.0.2 that does not explicitly lists the libraries included, but I've put it in the correct **libs** folder.

I included the Jar and Native Binaries available on the previous link. The .zip file was included in the build as:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.zip'])
```

The build seem to work. I verified that the native libraries: `cryptox.so` and `conceal.so` are included in apk/libs, and the other jar binary with packages like `com.facebook.crypto` is included within `classes.dex`.

Following is the activity code:

```
import com.facebook.crypto.Crypto;
import com.facebook.crypto.Entity;
import com.facebook.crypto.keychain.SharedPrefsBackedKeyChain;
import com.facebook.crypto.util.SystemNativeCryptoLibrary;

public class ConcealActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
public static String filename = "data.txt";
public static String filepath = "concealedata";
public static String TAG = "com.zing.ConcealActivity";
File myInternalFile;
Crypto crypto;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_conceal);

    Log.i(TAG, "created method.");
    ContextWrapper contextWrapper = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
    File directory = contextWrapper.getDir(filepath, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    myInternalFile = new File(directory, filename);
    crypto = new Crypto(new SharedPrefsBackedKeyChain(this), new SystemNativeCryptoLibrary());
    Button cencrypt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cencrypt);
    cencrypt.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button cdecrypt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cdecrypt);
    cdecrypt.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onclick method.");
    EditText myInputText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputText);
    TextView responseText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.responseText);
    String myData = "";

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.cencrypt:
            encryptandsave(myInputText.getText().toString().getBytes());
            myInputText.setText("");
            responseText.setText(readFile(myInternalFile));
            break;

        case R.id.cdecrypt:
            responseText.setText(readanddecrypt());
            break;
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_conceal, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

// The first condition below is always satisfied meaning the library isn't loaded correctly.

```
// Encrypts the data and saves to directory
public void encryptandsave(byte[] plainTextBytes) {
    try {
    // Check for whether the crypto functionality is available
    // This might fail if android does not load libaries correctly.
        if (!crypto.isAvailable()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Cipher unavailable.");
            return;
        }

        OutputStream fileStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(myInternalFile));
        OutputStream outputStream = crypto.getCipherOutputStream(fileStream, new Entity("Password"));
        outputStream.write(plainTextBytes);
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "EXCEPTION encryptandsave: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

// decode encrypted file and returns Bitmap
private String readanddecrypt() {
    try {
        if (!crypto.isAvailable()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Cipher unavailable.");
            return "";
        }
        FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(filename);
        InputStream inputStream = crypto.getCipherInputStream(fileStream, new Entity("Password"));
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        int read;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        inputStream.close();
        return out.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "EXCEPTION readanddecrypt: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}

public String readFile(File internalFile) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(internalFile);
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fis);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String strLine;
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(strLine);
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "EXCEPTION readFile: " + e.getMessage());
        return "";
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

}

I'm not sure whether there's some issue with the library or the code.

Inside the jar, it seems like the code is failing in

```
com.facebook.crypto.util.SystemNativeCryptoLibrary.java

private static final ArrayList<String> LIBS = new ArrayList<String>() {{
  add("cryptox");
  add("conceal");
}};
```

// It throws a java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError exception while executing this piece below:

```
for (String name : LIBS) {
  System.loadLibrary(name);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Assaf's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17131418/2514799) is the one that worked.
Below is the structure in which the libraries need to go.
Project:
|--lib:
|--|--armeabi:
|--|--|--.so files.

Note that the downloaded `libs.zip` has all the library files zipped in `libs` root folder, that needs to be changed to `lib` in order to get the libraries correctly bundled in `.apk`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put .so files to /app/src/main/jniLibs/ accordingly.

```
app
+-src
  +-main
    +-jniLibs
      +-armeabi
      | +-libconceal.so
      +-armeabi-v7a
      | +-libconceal.so
      +-mips
      +-x86
        +-libconceal.so
```