# implementing NDK library in Android Studio (android_serialport_api)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, serial-port, shared-libraries

I am attempting to write an android application (in Android Studio 1.3) to be installed on a Beaglebone Black using the [android_serialport_api](https://code.google.com/p/android-serialport-api/). I am new to NDK, and have been struggling quite a bit. The issue that I am now running into is accessing the library (libserial_port.so) from the SerialPort.java file. I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17131418/5016890) approach, but still have no luck. When I run the project, it compiles cleanly, opens, and then when a serial port is accessed I get the error:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError...
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load serial_port.so from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/com.example.blake.serialport2-1.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/com.example.blake.serialport2-1]: findLibrary returned null
```

I cannot for the life of me figure this out. I know that there are some answers that address portions of this question, but I was hoping that someone had experience with my particular issue.

Comment: Where is the .so file located on the device, and how are you trying to load it?

Comment: the .so file is currently being autogenerated at run time and placed in the: Project/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/serialPort2/android-serialport-api/jni/ameabi file. The SerialPort.java file attempts to load it with: Syste.loadLibrary("serial_port.so");