# Opencv java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, opencv

I'm following this for installing the opencv in Android Studio:

[How to use opencv in android studio using gradle build tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17767557/how-to-use-opencv-in-android-studio-using-gradle-build-tool)

But I have not figured out what happened with the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load mixed_sample: findLibrary returned null

After this code: `System.loadLibrary("mixed_sample");`

Any solution?

Comment: Where is the library? The native library should be in libs/<architecture> (usually arm) and named libmixed_sample.so.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/31564766/2092850