# NDK: how include *.so files in AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I have libs jar and *.so. I created Eclipse project as in tutorial (for this libs). I am now doing project in Android Studio, but system can't find *.so files. I make how in this - [Include .so library in apk in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683775/include-so-library-in-apk-in-android-studio) . My app does not find function in so libs. How to find them?
Log:

```
10-16 12:16:55.965: W/dalvikvm(4386): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lcom/atol/drivers/fptr/IFptrNative;
10-16 12:16:55.965: W/dalvikvm(4386): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41869438)
10-16 12:16:55.976: E/AndroidRuntime(4386): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-16 12:16:55.976: E/AndroidRuntime(4386): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

An error occurs when creating an object using a JAR library. She in turn poked *.so files, but to find what she needs. Who is to blame and what to do?

Comment: add a .so file from directory outside android project: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50713933/add-so-prebuilt-library-from-another-directory-to-apk

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Three options:

**One**

Copy yours *.SO libraries on your `libs` folder and put that on `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies
        {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
}
```

**Two**

Make a new folder on `src/main/jniLibs` and write that on your `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    //Another code 
    sourceSets {
        main {         
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jnilibs']          
        }
        //Another code 
    }//sourceSets tag close
}//Android tag close
```

**There**

Make a new folder on `src/main/jniLibs` and write that on your `build.gradle`:

```
//Another code....

    dependencies
    {
          compile fileTree(dir: "$buildDir/native-libs", include: 'native-libs.jar')
    }//end dependencies


    task nativeLibsToJar(type: Jar, description: 'create a jar archive of the native libs') {
        destinationDir file("$buildDir/native-libs")
        baseName 'native-libs'
        from fileTree(dir: 'src/main/jnilibs', include: '**/*.so')
        into 'lib/'
    }
    
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile)
     {
          compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn(nativeLibsToJar)
     }
```

Comment: Does not work. I create an object using a library JAR,but it works .so libraries. In Eclipse everything works. Can AndroidStudio generates incorrect links .so library or JAR file library tied to the project structure in Eclipse?

Comment: Thank you very much. This saved me after a week searching for solutions. Turned out that in my sourceSets.main.jniLibs.srcDirs there was just ["libs"]. Changing it to ['src/main/jniLibs'] made it work.

Answer (score 7):

**Current Solution**

Create the folder project/app/src/main/jniLibs, and then put your *.so files within their abi folders in that location. E.g.,

```
project/
├──libs/
|  └── *.jar       <-- if your library has jar files, they go here
├──src/
   └── main/
       ├── AndroidManifest.xml
       ├── java/
       └── jniLibs/ 
           ├── arm64-v8a/                       <-- ARM 64bit
           │   └── yourlib.so
           ├── armeabi-v7a/                     <-- ARM 32bit
           │   └── yourlib.so
           └── x86/                             <-- Intel 32bit
               └── yourlib.so
```

**Deprecated solution**

Add both code snippets in your module gradle.build file as a dependency:

```
compile fileTree(dir: "$buildDir/native-libs", include: 'native-libs.jar')
How to create this custom jar:

task nativeLibsToJar(type: Jar, description: 'create a jar archive of the native libs') {
    destinationDir file("$buildDir/native-libs")
    baseName 'native-libs'
    from fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '**/*.so')
    into 'lib/'
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn(nativeLibsToJar)
}
```

---

---

Comment: Remember to include this in your build.gradle
sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jniLibs']
        }
    }
If the content between the [square brackets] is different, Android Studio will not load the so libraries correctly into the APK and may skip some libraries you need. This gave me headaches for a whole week.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your .so files inside a folder named lib (it's not libs and should be lib). It should be in the same structure it should be in the APK file.

Structure

```
Project:
|--lib:
|--|--armeabi:
|--|--|--.so files.
```

Then an armeabi folder where insert all `.so` files. Then zip the folder into a .zip.Rename the .zip file into armeabi.jar and add the line 
`compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')`
 into `dependencies {}` in the gradle's build file.

For more info and alternate method please see [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683775/include-so-library-in-apk-in-android-studio) and [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357687/how-to-include-so-library-in-android-studio)

Comment: Does not work. I create an object using a library JAR,but it works .so libraries. In Eclipse everything works. Can AndroidStudio generates incorrect links .so library or JAR file library tied to the project structure in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

Create folder name "jniLibs" inside src/main folder and add All the folders containing your "*.so" file and sync and run your application. No other steps required.