# Can not resolve corresponding JNI Function

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I did not find a solution to my problem in similar threads like:
[Cannot resolve corresponding JNI function with .so file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37034004/cannot-resolve-corresponding-jni-function-with-so-file)
I have an android project written with Eclipse ADT plugin and I needed to import it into android studio. In the eclipse workspace there were .so files and when I imported it into android studio the .so files are imported into jnilibs under main folder. 
When I open the classes containing native method calls I got "Cannot resolve corresponding JNI function" and the project does not work well even it is compiled without problems but as functionality the project does not work well.

Comment: Please specify exactly what _"does not work well"_ means.

Comment: when I open the class that contains native method calls I get can not resolve errors with them and the .so library should do something but don't?

Comment: Actually my .so files are responsible for pairing Zigbee sensors with my hub. They work without problems (Pairing sensors )with eclipse but could not with android studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue noted above by reimporting the project from eclipse and everything work well now.
Maybe it missed importing something..