# How to use c lib(.so) from android?

Tags: android, c, android-studio, android-ndk, shared-libraries

*Currently i am working on Android NDK and successfully implementing C code in **jni** and calling  c code using jni on android studio 1.5.*

But now as per as my project requirement i am not using c code on my android project so i am using only ***.so*** **shared library**.

I got this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357687/how-to-include-so-library-in-android-studio) and used **sqlcipher** but still i don't have enough knowledge about how to add or call   .so shared library.

Refer above link and example, update my project but following getting error

**java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app/com.abc.xyz-2/lib/arm/libV1.so" has bad ELF magic**

**Problem:**

1. How to call .so shared library from android.
2. How to include .so files on my project.

Answer (score 2):

Read first my answer here to add *.so libraries:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33164947/3626214

And now, read here how to solve `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed:` on Android 6.X devices because you'll get an error on this devices when you add *.so libraries:

**build.gradle**

```
android
        {

            //23 or higher
            compileSdkVersion 23
            buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"


 defaultConfig
                    {
                        ...
                        //important code, write API 22
                        targetSdkVersion 22
                       ...
                    }

...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for very fast reply.. let me check but i have one more query how do i call C function??

Comment: You can use a method `private native int/void/boolean nameMethod` to call native methods on yours activities, but that is another question, you can make another question to do that, another users may also need it in the future, and i'm sure people answer you faster too when you show your code problems. Try first to add libraries and don't get any compile error and later make another question.

Comment: @Amit : Hi Amit, I am working on the same issue, I have a .so file and now I need to import to my android Application and use the library. So how do we call the C functions??

Comment: @Aspicas : Can you pls let me know how we can call methods in java using JNI from a already .SO. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55263368/calling-so-functions-from-a-java-class-using-jni

Comment: @Amit : Please refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55263368/calling-so-functions-from-a-java-class-using-jni