# AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: couldn't find "libgnustl_shared.so"

Tags: android, eclipse, migration

I have made a research regarding this question but no answer helped.
I am new to Android so please ask for more sources and info then I initially publish.
I have migrated our company app from Eclipse to Android Studio but still get this fatal:

```
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.streamunlimited.stream700, PID: 6297
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.streamunlimited.stream700-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.streamunlimited.stream700-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libgnustl_shared.so"
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:367)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
at com.streamunlimited.stream700.DeviceOverviewActivity.<clinit>(DeviceOverviewActivity.java:86)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1068)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2365)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2524)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1391)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Here is build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 16
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

    // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
    // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
    // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
    // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
    // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
    // by a similar customization.
    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
}
}
```

Application.mk:

```
APP_OPTIM       := debug        # release
APP_PLATFORM    := android-8
APP_STL         := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS    += -frtti 
APP_CPPFLAGS    += -fexceptions
APP_CPPFLAGS    += -DANDROID
```

Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

# additional include directories
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += /opt/sca-android-debug/include          \
                ../../../lib/RemoteBrowser/             \
                ../../../lib/NetAPI/                    \
                ../../../lib/NetAPI/core                \
                ../../../lib/NetAPI/client              \
                ../../../lib/NetAPI/interface           \
                ../../../lib/NetAPI/server              \
                ../../../lib/Stream800API/              \
                ../../../lib/Stream800API/src           \
                ../../../lib/Stream800API/lib/picojson  \
                ../../../lib/Stream800API/src/library   \

# compiler flags
#LOCAL_CFLAGS     += -DPOCO_ANDROID -DPOCO_NO_FPENVIRONMENT -DPOCO_NO_WSTRING -DPOCO_NO_SHAREDMEMORY
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS   += -g -O0

# linker flags
LOCAL_LDLIBS     += -L/opt/sca-android-debug/lib -llog -lPocoNetd -lPocoDatad -lPocoUtild -lPocoXMLd -lPocoFoundationd  

# we will create this library
LOCAL_MODULE    := RemoteApi

# files to compile
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := RemoteApi.cpp

REMOTE_BROWSER  := \
../../../../lib/RemoteBrowser/RemoteBrowser.cpp             \
../../../../lib/RemoteBrowser/NetAPIRemoteBrowser.cpp       \
../../../../lib/RemoteBrowser/RemoteBrowser_wrap.cxx        \

NETAPI_CLIENT   := \
../../../../lib/NetAPI/client/NetAPI_Client.cpp             \
../../../../lib/NetAPI/client/NetAPI_Event_Handlers.cpp     \
../../../../lib/NetAPI/client/NetAPI_TCP_Client.cpp

NETAPI_CORE := \
../../../../lib/NetAPI/core/NetAPI_Commands.cpp             \
../../../../lib/NetAPI/core/NetAPI_Connection.cpp           \
../../../../lib/NetAPI/core/NetAPI_Core.cpp                 \
../../../../lib/NetAPI/core/NetAPI_Data.cpp                 \
../../../../lib/NetAPI/core/NetAPI_Events.cpp               \
../../../../lib/NetAPI/core/NetAPI_Init.cpp                 \
../../../../lib/NetAPI/core/NetAPI_Module.cpp               \
../../../../lib/NetAPI/core/NetAPI_Module_Basic.cpp         \
../../../../lib/NetAPI/core/NetAPI_Module_Core.cpp          \
../../../../lib/NetAPI/core/NetAPI_Module_Debug.cpp         \
../../../../lib/NetAPI/core/NetAPI_Protocol_XML.cpp         \
../../../../lib/NetAPI/core/NetAPI_TCP_Transport.cpp        

NETAPI_INTERFACE    := \
../../../../lib/NetAPI/interface/NetAPI_Controller_Interface.cpp    \
../../../../lib/NetAPI/interface/NetAPI_UI_Interface.cpp            \

NETAPI_SERVER   := \
../../../../lib/NetAPI/server/NetAPI_Server.cpp             \
../../../../lib/NetAPI/server/NetAPI_TCP_Server.cpp         \
../../../../lib/NetAPI/server/NetAPI_Test_Server.cpp        \

NETAPI_PREFIX   := \
../../../../lib/NetAPI/Prefix.cpp   

STREAM800API_LIB    := \
../../../../lib/Stream800API/src/library/Commands.cpp       \
../../../../lib/Stream800API/src/library/Controller.cpp     \
../../../../lib/Stream800API/src/library/EventHandler.cpp   \
../../../../lib/Stream800API/src/library/EventPoller.cpp    \
../../../../lib/Stream800API/src/library/Helpers.cpp        \
../../../../lib/Stream800API/src/library/HTTPTransport.cpp  \
../../../../lib/Stream800API/src/library/StreamAPI.cpp      \

LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(REMOTE_BROWSER)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(NETAPI_CLIENT)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(NETAPI_CORE)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(NETAPI_INTERFACE)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(NETAPI_PREFIX)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(NETAPI_SERVER)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(STREAM800API_LIB)


# NETAPI_FILES := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)../../../../lib/NetAPI/*.cpp)
# NETAPI_FILES := $(MY_FILES:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)
# LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(NETAPI_FILES)

LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libgnustl_shared 

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: Check my answer here to add *.so libraries, maybe you need to use another way to do. http://stackoverflow.com/a/33164947/3626214

Comment: Not working for me.