# AVD crashes saying 'Unfortunately, libcocos2dx has crashed'

Tags: android, android-studio, cocos2d-x

I just loaded my app created by cocos2dx-3.10 and when I open with it an AVD (again I haven't done any modifications to the app) the app crashes and gives the error: Unfortunately, libcocos2dx has crashed.

here is what I get in my android Monitor:

```
03-05 18:34:56.668 1435-1435/? D/dalvikvm: Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
03-05 18:34:56.989 1435-1435/com.trying.name E/Trace: error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-05 18:34:57.419 1435-1435/com.trying.name D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
03-05 18:34:57.419 1435-1435/com.trying.name W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2f2b288)
03-05 18:34:57.518 1435-1435/com.trying.name E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                               java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load cocos2dcpp: findLibrary returned null
                                                                   at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
                                                                   at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
                                                                   at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxActivity.onLoadNativeLibraries(Cocos2dxActivity.java:248)
                                                                   at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxActivity.onCreate(Cocos2dxActivity.java:263)
                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-05 18:35:11.559 1435-1435/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 1435 SIG: 9
```

Comment: The stack trace indicates you are trying to load a native library. Is the library included in your APK?

Comment: I'm sorry if I sound like an idiot, but I don't know what that means. Could you please teach me how to see this?

Comment: This line: load cocos2dcpp: findLibrary returned null. This means you do not have the native library in your APK, it was not included.

Comment: so what do I do to include it? I followed the cocos2d-x course to get this far, I don't know very much :( sorry for bad english

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683775/include-so-library-in-apk-in-android-studio

Comment: what is in the native library, and how do I add this?

Comment: Check your lib\armeabi directory to see whether there is `libcocos2dcpp.so` file.