# Android Studio: Android Manifest doesn't exists or has incorrect root tag

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-studio

I got this error on Android Studio (AS):
[image]

## How I got it:

I created an AS Project from scratch and everything was fine.
Then a popup showed up, and (if I recall correctly) was saying something like: "`Android Framework detected`". I pressed "Yes' and some changes happened to the project/module. And after that I got the above error

#### Edit:

In my case the problem was not `Gradle` related. It had to do with `IntelliJ`/`Android Studio` configuration, an `.iml` file in particular.
I realized that after reading this informative post [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to build an android library with Android Studio and gradle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16718026/how-to-build-an-android-library-with-android-studio-and-gradle)

Comment: I already read that post, when I was trying to migrate another project to AndStudio. But this project i started if from scratch from AndStudio, and I had no problems since today! I will read again that question, and also basic gradle documentation. If that question solves my problem I 'll come back here and delete my question

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for that without recreating the project?
I am suffering from this issue as well. Creating a new project worked, but now I am having a problem again. I do not want to recreate the project twice a day..

Comment: Hey @MikeT unfortunately no! I read the basics about gradle from the link I provided, and then I realised that it was somehow IntelliJ related, with the IML file. I suggest to consult google before applying any auto-solutions from Android Studio!

Comment: Hi @Paschalis, I just managed to get my project working again, but only after downloading the old AS 0.3.1. I have no issues with this build of AS. However, I am disappointed because this problem cost me nearly a day.

Comment: I faced this error recently. This error may come alone or with the possible outcome of this issue [https://stackoverflow.com/q/52513097/5685911]

Answer (score 278, accepted):

On Android Studio v0.8.2 clicking on `Sync project with Gradle files` button solved my problem.

[image: Screenshot of Android Studio toolbar with "Sync project with Grandle files" button highlighted.]

**update**

Thanks to the comment of [jaumard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/541867/jaumard). If the `Sync project with Gradle files` it's not visible you have to open the Gradle panel and click sync icon on top the toolbar.

Comment: Worked for me. I tried Synchronize in the context menu but that didn't work but pressing this button did. Thanks for the picture!

Comment: Came about when I tried to change Project name, directory, and such.

Comment: Funny enough, after a year, I faced this problem again.
While on the first time the error was very weird, this time a pretty straightforward and only a *sync* was necessary. (that's why I am accepting the answer)
However, it can be caused by different reasons, that's why there are various answers..

Comment: The button moved a bit in 0.8.14, but its still there, and it still helps.

Comment: For people with intelliJ sync button is not visible you have to open Gradle panel and click sync icon on top toolbar

Comment: I had the same issue after I moved my project to a different folder. Tried all possible solution and this "magic icon" is the only one that fix my problem. Kudo

Comment: ^ same here, I had this issue when I changed the folder name. Then I synced the project and it worked! Thanks.

Comment: All "gradle" options in the "find action" menu are disabled for me, yet I have this error.

Comment: Hello i am new in Android studio. i am import my ionic framework project in android studio but its run time give Error "Android Manifest doesn't exists or has incorrect root tag" which one you tell above button it's not i am seen in my android studio. please help me. and i am using MAC System.

Answer (score 18):

Just call (in any case) File -> Invalidate Caches and Restart....

Comment: was the only solution here that worked for me. thank you @armansimonyan13

Comment: This makes no difference.

Comment: I am using MAC OS.(10.13.2) - Android Studio (3.3.2). This solution is not working for me ?? Any suggestion will appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

In my case:

settings.gradle file was empty. I added defualt code:

```
include ':app'
```

Then I clicked

[image: Sync Project with Gradle Files]

Then project start works.

Comment: I am using MAC OS.(10.13.2) - Android Studio (3.3.2). 
This Button is not available for me. Can you guide me for Manual update OR any flow to visible this button ??
Any suggestion will appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Double check that under project structure / module / Manifest file it points to the correct manifest file in your code and not the one in generated sources.

This is true for both Android Studio and Intelli J. Sometime when you import project from existing sources it prefer the manifest file inside the generates sources directory.

Comment: found the solution in git, after moving a project to a differnt folder, as described, some config after re-opening (importing) was wrong.

Comment: @cv2, can you provide me the link for the solution in git ?

Comment: Hey there, sorry that wasn't a public project. Just delete your complete configurations (also hidden folders) and try to reimport everything "clean" again. Good luck!

Answer (score 7):

What helped for me was:

- delete ***.gradle/*** folder
- delete ***.idea/*** folder
- delete ****.idea*** file
- reopen Android Studio
- import from gradle as Android Studio then suggests

Answer (score 5):

I ran into a similar problem. Looks like my .../src directory for whatever reason moved under my .../lib directory. I moved it out of the /lib directory. Now both /lib and /src are at the same level. After a couple of clean rebuilds and restarts of Android studio everything is back to normal. My emulator started up fine.

You might want to check your directory structure. Compare the directory structure with a working project. You might be able to see the difference.

Answer (score 3):

Moving my `AndroidManifest.xml` to `PROJECT_NAME/src/main` fixed the issue.

Comment: It is not, because the **AndroidManifest.xml** used to be in a different location which worked before.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same errormessage and noticed I had 2 MYPROJECTNAME.iml files, but with a different casing  of MYPROJECTNAME. I created this situation after checking out from SVN the project into a directory with the casing error.
Just throw away the IML file with the wrong casing, after saving the content of both and use the content that works

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with a multi-module project when I renamed the app module. In my case to solve the problem I had to manually update the app module name in the project's settings.gradle file (Android Studio didn't update that value)

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me. Found that i had wrongly opened the parent folder of the actual project in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was my **AndroidManifest.xml** file, it was all messed up due to a new library that I added in my  **build.gradle**.
So I took the **AndroidManifest.xml** from my latest commit on Git and I replaced it the current one, and also my **settings.gradle** was empty so I added **include ':app'**.

Hope it helps, and happy coding !

Answer (score 0):

Facing same issue, resolve after adding the missing **build.gradle** file in root project.