# Project Name in Android Studio Does Not Change

Tags: android-studio

I followed the instructions here [Change project name on Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276872/change-project-name-on-android-studio) and while my project name in the project explorer changed, the project name in the top IDE bar does not(the very top left of the IDE window).  I renamed the project by right clicking the project name, updated the manifest's app_name and package name.

Comment: See [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49906736/6607935). Solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug where some pointers in the duplicate project still point to the original project.  I experience this only when using "Open Project" to bring the duplicate up in AS.  This is solved by using the "Import Project" instead and then refactoring and renaming accordingly.

This brings up another issue, however.  While the naming is correct, something is still pointing to the original, because launching either the original or the duplicate on the device replaces the other on the home screen.

Answer (score 0):

With Android Studio off, I renamed the project folder in Explorer and restarted Android Studio and imported project. Now this created another .iml in the project folder so I went ahead and deleted the old .iml .
(it seems to have correctly changed the app.iml in src also)
I hope this is all there is to it.

Answer (score 0):

this work for me:

Close android studio

Change project root directory name

Open android studio

Open the project(not from local history but by browsing to it)