# How to change name of project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, ide, projects-and-solutions

Imported an eclipse project into Android Studio and saved it in a new folder. Changed the package name and everything to new names but the Project's name is still the one from the old project.

How do I change the pointed name into something else?

[image: project name]

Comment: Keep in mind that an Eclipse project is an Android Studio module. By right clicking into the module name, and going to Refactor > Rename, you could do the rename

Comment: I had already renamed the module from AS but the old project name remains on top of AS window!

Comment: clean, build, reopen? reimport?

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change project name on Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276872/change-project-name-on-android-studio)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Try changing the contents of this file: `C:\Path\To\Project\.idea\.name`

Comment: Thanx a lot! That did the trick! Now everywhere the new name is shown.

Comment: You need to restart AndroidStudio ... ;)

Comment: Even after restarting Android Studio, it didn't worked for me. I'm using Studio 2.0

Comment: Dont work on mac, Android studio 2.22 , I dont even have the file .idea/.name

Answer (score 2):

1. Change the name in manifest file.
   `android:label="@string/app_name"`
2. There's a build.gradle file inside your app folder. Change the package name from there. Make sure you edit the build.gradle file inside your app folder, not the one in the root of your project.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to change only the name of the application to enter src->main->res->values->strings.xml ​​and change the name to the new

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this in your `settings.gradle` file:

```
rootProject.name = "YOUR_PROJECT_NAME"
```

After restarting of Android Studio it will also change text in title bar to `YOUR_PROJECT_NAME`.

Tested on Android Studio 2.2 RC2

Answer (score 0):

change rootProject.name in settings.gradle file

```
settings.gradle

    rootProject.name = 'NewAppName'
```

Answer (score -1):

Android Studio's Refactor will help you. Just click rename your project with refactoring

Answer (score -1):

Try to change **app_name** string in strings.xml

> `<string name="app_name">My Application</string>`