# How to change project's folder name in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I found this solution: [How to change name of project in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26933150/how-to-change-name-of-project-in-android-studio?s=4|0.3900), but doesn't seem to be working nad I don't want to damage anything so my question - how to change project's folder name?

I can't find any internal solution, so maybe You have any tricks up the sleeves.

Answer (score 0):

1)Select the Entry "Project" in top-left side on the IDE, under the name of your project (The default entry is "Android")
2)Right-click on the name of project, select Refractor->Rename

Comment: I get `Can't rename root module` error

Answer (score 0):

This trick worked for me nicely. Follow these steps:

STEP 1: Open Android Studio

STEP 2: Create a new project with the **desired name**.

STEP 3: Close Android Studio.

STEP 4: Find the **src** folder in your new project directory. **Delete** it and **replace** it with **src** folder of the old project.

STEP 5: All done. Open your project by browsing through the link **Open an existing Android Studio Project**.

[image]

[image]