# Pro Version uploading to Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

i've developed an app for Android. I made a isPro = 1/0 String in my strings.xml so i just have to develope one app and to upload them i just would have to change the value in the strings.xml

I wanted to upload the "Pro" app on the Play Store but i get the error, that the package name already exists. I already renamed my Project once, and that was really annoying. Do I have to copy the project or is there an easier solution?

Thanks for any help and sorry for my bad english :)

Answer (score 0):

In your AndroidManifest.xml there is an `package` attribute on your `<manifest>` tag. Just change that into something else and it should work.

Comment: That's not enough. I think i just have to copy the Project and rename the Package like here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276872/change-project-name-on-android-studio/27232067#27232067)[/link]. I guess I just have to keep both projects up to date. I was hoping i could to this from one project, but i think that is not possible