# Renaming android project - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, rename

I think it was a default title, but after finally finishing an App I just realised that the name of it is "Active App"

Now, I wanted to rename the App to "Bonus Calc".

I created a new Project called "Bonus Calc" and copied the code from the "Active App" xml files, java files etc, and replaced any code that said "activeapp" with "bonuscalc", including package names etc.

I clearly renamed everything since the code is compiling and running fine on my phone.

However the name of the app in my phone is still "Active App".

Comment: Are you 100% sure you replaced everything? Active App is loaded from your strings.xml, normally.

Comment: just to be 100% sure, uninstall "Active App" manually from your phone and then retry installing your renamed app!!  BTW, Why you did not used "Refactor -> Rename" option? This should have renamed your app.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276872/change-project-name-on-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

the name of the app is named in the android manifest. just change the name there and it will be done.
and as to your second problem that i saw - you went through alot just to rename your project. next time just right click on your project -> choose "refactor" -> and than "rename".

Comment: That was what I had initially done and the name didn't change in my phone for some reason.

Comment: maybe you've done something wrong.. it will help if you post your manifest here