# Changing Project Company Name in Android Studio

Tags: github, android-studio, google-play-services

I have an ongoing Project about to finish and before publishing wanted to change the company name without rewriting the code or messing up my GitHub repository. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

To change the name of your repository on GitHub, follow the instructions on their page, "[Renaming a repository](https://help.github.com/articles/renaming-a-repository/)."

To change the name of your project in Android Studio, [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276872/change-project-name-on-android-studio) might help.

Comment: But I want to change my company domain name of my ongoing project in Android Studio.

Comment: Can you change the repository's name on GitHub, re-clone the repository on your machine, and start a new project in Android Studio with the new domain name?