# How to rename the package name in android studio correctly

Tags: android-studio

I would like to know how to change the package name my project without having any errors. I tried so many times, but it ended with so many errors. Such as errors in import statements, R class errors....etc
Please help me with this issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try refactoring in IDE.In Eclipse, select the package from package explorer, then refactor(`ALT+SHIFT+R`)

Comment: Thanks for response Gangaraju, but it didn't solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

change the package name manually in the manifest file. Click on your R.java class and the press F6 (Refactor->Move...). It will allow you to move the class to another package, and all references to that class will be updated.Refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/27232067/5710650