# Renaming package in Android Studio 2.1

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a project up and running what I want to do it's to rename that project, package, applicationID to something different on Android Studio 2.1 I have tried with all links below:

[Android Studio Rename Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29092698/2001610
[Change project name on Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276872/change-project-name-on-android-studio/27232067#27232067)
[Change project name on Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276872/change-project-name-on-android-studio)

Trying with all those links I got  the following errors:

> "build.config and R files are not getting generated "

and the

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>   No matching client found for package name 'com.example.project'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio Rename Package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package)

Answer (score 0):

Those links are correct, so maybe you are not doing something properly.
Check that the **package name**, and the name package name that appear in the **AndroidManifest** and **Gradle** are the same.

Answer (score -1):

follow this steps to change Package name:
[Click on setting icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwFAr.png)

[Untick Compact Empty Middle Packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tn3jq.png)

Right Click on (com,example,example) each on click on it right click and choose

Refactor --> Rename then lick ok

Comment: The question indicates that he has try this solution. You are not giving any useful info.

Comment: @SamuelPS Why you are talking to me?? i gave the answer i know to him