# Rename a project in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

Is there an option to change my project name in Android Studio ?
I named it My Application but now I want to change it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change project name on Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276872/change-project-name-on-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

right click on project click on **File Path**

then go to project location and rename the folder and re open the project

and clean and build.

Comment: It worked thank you and how do I change it on phone? The application stil called myapplication on my phone.