# Changing package name and application ID

Tags: android, crashlytics-android

I wanted to **change package name** and **application id** for my current project so I did that by **refractor** rename and **open module settings** respectively.

But here's is two things I am worried which I guess might create a problem.

1. The name of my project is still the same earlier if my package name was **com.company.Abc** then project name was **Abc** so I decided to keep **com.company.Xyz** but the project name remains **Abc**.
   But I guess this will not be problem since project name is not associated with package name though I wanted to change.

Things I am worried:  There is a file name **Abc.iml** which is a **configuration** file but after refractor I didn't get any **Xyz.iml**, I don't know what this will do.

2. The major problem which I am facing is I am using **fabric crashlytics** in my current project and in account the project is showing the **previous** project id. I have changed the app name but don't know how to change this. I am sure this will not report anything since I already refractor the package name and project id

Comment: Just try this one. It worked for me:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/28324892/6265645

Comment: @Dr0xiii what about fabric crashlytics ?

Comment: you can change the name in the settings of fabric. you have to be admin to do this

Comment: @Dr0xiii Yes I am the admin but how to change it there is no option to change it.

Comment: @Dr0xiii First tell me how to change the whole domain like I have com.abc.xyz so I want to change "abc" too.

Comment: if you want to change the whole application id then you can set this in your build.gradle file like this `applicationId 'com.xyz.xyz'`

Comment: @Dr0xiii Earlier my application id was com.abc.form and package name was com.abc.xyz and it was running properly, So i guess application id and package name is not the same thing and I have asked "how to change company domain" not application ID

Comment: your initial question was "Changing package name and application ID" so i guess you asked how to change the application ID. of course you can refactor the names of your packages. just open the android-view of your project, click on the gear icon and deselect "compact empty middle packages" and refactor all your packages

Comment: @Dr0xiii yeah now tell me where is this code since i am not getting it

Comment: look at this... http://stackoverflow.com/a/29092698/6265645

Comment: @Dr0xiii Thanks I have changed it both company domain and package name.....but in fabric setting I still can't change the name