# How do i change the name of my project in Android Studio?

Tags: android

I am creating a project which has to be named as "Emergency Helper". When i started creating the project,I named it as "Emeregency Helper". I want to rename it as "Emergency Helper".Kindly help!

Comment: the name are same..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276872/change-project-name-on-android-studio

Comment: There's a build.gradle file inside your app folder. You have to change the applicationId in there, modify it from AndroidManifest file, as well. Then sync your project with gradle, clean it and rebuild it.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the name that is shown in the title bar in the file ".idea/.name".

Answer (score 0):

Open AndroidManifest file Under Manifests and rename your app name there.

```
android:label="@string/app_name"
```

Also If you want to rename the package too then 
Select gear icon just below the Run button
Untick 2nd option that is "Compact empty middle packages"
  This will expand the java directories.
Now rename directories as you want by selecting Refactor-Rename.
Enter the new name and click on Rename package
Click on Do Refactor at the bottom left corner.

Let it do its work.