# Creating a "pro" version of an app with different package name

Tags: java, android, package, refactoring

I would like to create a "pro" version of my Android app.
I have to slightly change the app name, and the package name, and so on.
I tried the refactor command (renaming com.appname.app into com.appname.pro.app) but I see that nothing changed.
How to achieve the real name refactoring?

Comment: Make sure you're renaming with subpackages.

Comment: Check that answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276872/change-project-name-on-android-studio

Comment: @lexicore I do not find this option

Comment: if the biggest difference between your "pro" and your other version is the naming of a package, why bother?

Comment: @Stultuske I'm going to make some change after I have a new project for the separate pro app

Answer (score 0):

First, select the settings [image: icon] and then

Then uncheck compact empty middle package, then refractor (shift+F6) each package name and make sure it changes in manifest and all over and clean and rebuild the project
    Also, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276872/change-project-name-on-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using `Gradle` as a build tool.
You should use `productFlavors` to achieve this.

***Here's how :***

```
android {
    productFlavors {
        free {
           applicationId "xyz.some.domain.free"
        }
        pro {
           applicationId "xyz.some.domain.pro"
        }
    }
}
```

place the above `code` inside your `app` level `build.gradle` file. To customise it more, read [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html).

You can then install pro/free version using `Gradle` tasks.