# 2 Activities and Application name

Tags: java, android

I have 2 activities with names: "loginActivity" and Main activity "mainActivity".

Is it possible to set the name of Application different like Main activity?

When I'm trying to set android: label in `<application>` app still have the name of my MainActivity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.fiona.fragment_app">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

    <application
        tools:replace = "icon"
        android:name="com.example.fiona.fragment_app.activity.MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="DATABASE"
            android:value="dbb.db" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="VERSION"
            android:value="1" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="QUERY_LOG"
            android:value="true" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME"
            android:value="com.example.fiona.fragment_app" />

        <activity
            android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
            android:label="MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">

        </activity>

        <service android:name=".services.MainService" />

        <activity
            android:name=".activity.LoginActivity"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:label="loginActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

[it is what I want to change CLICK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLF5l.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can change your app name in values -> strings.xml

Comment: and I get "unresolved class", in android name need to be class of app

Comment: So, you want to rename your app title to be Main activity ?

Comment: no, i want to set name name of my Application "Animals" but don't want change name of mainactivity and loginactivity

Comment: Open values -> strings.xml and do
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Animals</string>
</resources>

Comment: Yes, I have this <string name="app_name">Animals</string> and still under Icon my app i have "login Activity"

Comment: By doing this, the name of the application must be changed. Are you talking about the name shown below the icon in android or the name shown in the Action Bar ?

Comment: under icon in menu device

Comment: Please add a screenshot where you want to change the name.

Comment: i can't remove this, MyApplication is activity with global context

Comment: Then you should click on Build and clean the project. Then rebuild and execute.

Comment: still "loginactivity"

Comment: Then there might be some error in your code. You can either upload on github and send me a link or make a zip and mail it to rajgar114@gmail.com.

Comment: i think i cant have different label app than main activity

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what do you mean about "application" name! but if you mean Project name and you want to change your project name you can use the link below:

[Change project name on Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276872/change-project-name-on-android-studio)

I think this will help you.

Comment: application name is a text under icon (in menu device)

Comment: As a photo you uploaded, What device do you run this app? If you run on an Emulator of Android Studio, try to uninstall and run (rebuild) your app from Android studio (after you change the name in Values -> Strings.xml), so this would be ok. or If you run this on your phone, you should do the same.

Comment: i think i cant have different label app than main activity

Comment: @companyn2 Then it should be a mistake in your code!
By the way, accept my edit on your question because your question is grammatically wrong and if you don't accept the edit, you will give more negative in the future from other users.

Answer (score -1):

You can change your application name whenever you want.

> Go to res -> values -> strings.xml

Change name as you want.

[image: see this screenshot]

Comment: I mean text under icon in menu device, do you have Massenger in phone ? so under blue icon u have text "Messenger" i want to change this

Comment: I didn't get. What do you mean by menu device?

Comment: do you have phone ? do you have application :) ? so every application have a name ! :) check my screen in question

Comment: That is what the application name present in strings.xml

Comment: Go to setting-> installed apps and select the app and uninstall for all user and try to build it and  installing it again, after changing app name in strings.xml

Comment: still "loginactivity"

Comment: yes i do, i think i cant have different label app than main activity