# Android Stuido, Can't run the app on my device after changing application name

Tags: android-studio

I renamed my app from LoginRegister to RideMe,
After changing while I'm trying to run my app on my device, I get the following error

```
Installation failed with message Invalid File: C:\Users\barakhome\AndroidStudioProjects\LoginRegister\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_4.apk.
```

The file it's looking still in the "old" path since `LoginRegister` has been changed to `RideMe`
[image]

Any way to fix it?

Thanks in advance

Note* the app is running fine via emulator
Note2* after chaning the app name I cleaned and re-build the app.

Comment: here is about how to rename app: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276872/change-project-name-on-android-studio

Comment: As the dialog suggests uninstalling the old version might help.

Comment: @shizhen I already renamed my project name accordingto this guide and as I mentioned, it works fine via emulator.   
@MarkusKauppinen, I did try that and I get another error  
`Unknown failure (at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:697))
Error while Installing APKs`

Comment: With a help of a friend I fixed it.  
The solution to this is to build apk after cleaning project.  
Build -> Build APK(s)