# Change the root project name in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I would like to copy my Android project and create a new project from the same files just with a different name and different project. The purpose of this is so I can have a second version of my app which is ad supported.

Comment: Why don't you use git to create a new branch of your project?

Answer (score 0):

Copy past your project in new directory and follow this link -> [Change project root directory name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28324892/12676506)

Or you can use git and create a new branch of your project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Git](https://git-scm.com/) to manage your local project, and [Github](https://github.com/) to create a private project and upload your project there. This is one of the best ways to manage your code and create a new app version.

If you don't want to use them, you may need:

1. copy all files to a given directory;
2. change the directory name of your package;
3. replace all package name in your AS;
4. change your gradle file of your app to change application id.