# How to Change name of Kotlin android Project In android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

Where Can I change name of the project in Android Studio Kotlin language

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change project name on Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276872/change-project-name-on-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

You have to close Android Studio then look for your project directory in File Explorer. Then you have to rename the root directory then open up Android Studio again. However, you will have to browse your project as it will not be accessible from the project history list.