# how to run google_maps_flutter example

Tags: flutter, google-maps

I want to run the example of google_maps_flutter. So I downloaded the code from https://github.com/flutter/plugins and open the /plugins/tree/master/packages/google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter using android studio.

In the README.md file, it said

> ### Usage
>
> To use this plugin, add `google_maps_flutter` as a [dependency in your
> pubspec.yaml file](https://flutter.io/platform-plugins/).

After I added the

```
dependencies:
  google_maps_flutter: ^1.0.3
```

it shows

> Error on line 11, column 3 of pubspec.yaml: A package may not list
> itself as a dependency.    ╷ 11 │   google_maps_flutter: ^1.0.3    │
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    ╵ pub get failed (65;    ╵)

After I changed line 1 from `name: google_maps_flutter` to `name: google_maps_flutter_eg`, it shows

> Error on line 1, column 7 of ../pubspec.yaml: "name" field doesn't
> match expected name "google_maps_flutter".   ╷ 1 │ name:
> google_maps_flutter_eg   │       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ╵ pub get
> failed (65;   ╵)

how can i change the name of this project for me to run the example?

below is the pubspec.yaml

```
name: google_maps_flutter
description: A Flutter plugin for integrating Google Maps in iOS and Android applications.
homepage: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter
version: 1.0.7

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle: ^1.0.0
  google_maps_flutter_platform_interface: ^1.0.4
  google_maps_flutter: ^1.0.6

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # TODO(iskakaushik): The following dependencies can be removed once
  # https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/2101 is resolved.
  flutter_driver:
    sdk: flutter
  test: ^1.6.0
  pedantic: ^1.8.0
  plugin_platform_interface: ^1.0.2
  mockito: ^4.1.1

flutter:
  plugin:
    platforms:
      android:
        package: io.flutter.plugins.googlemaps
        pluginClass: GoogleMapsPlugin
      ios:
        pluginClass: FLTGoogleMapsPlugin

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"
  flutter: ">=1.22.0 <2.0.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a dependency that has the same name as your project.You need to change the name.

Comment: could you upload screenshot of pubspec.yaml file?

Comment: I suppose that your project name is "google_maps_flutter" ,so i edited my answer.

Comment: published pubspec.yaml above. But the original project name google_maps_flutter is the same as the dependency which produces the error.

Comment: if you change your project name,error is disappear.

Comment: how can i change the project name in android studio?

Comment: look at this url : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276872/change-project-name-on-android-studio

Comment: i did rename the project folder, run flutter clean, then rename the rootProject.name android/settings.gradle and rename the s.name in ios/google_maps_flutter.podspec and still receiving error Error on line 1, column 7 of ../pubspec.yaml: "name" field doesn't match expected name "google_maps_flutter".

Comment: You also have to rename the `name` property in your `pubspec.yaml` file to your the name of your project folder.