# What are all the different names for apps, projects, modules etc in Android Studio

Tags: android, names

Changing names in Android Studio is a nightmare, particularly as it seems to use a number of different names. I think I worked out how to change most of them, but what is this (see yellow highlighting on screenshot attached) and how do I change it?

[image: screenshot highlighted to show issue]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change project name on Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276872/change-project-name-on-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

for your problem with names, if you want to change a name of a file/variable in all of the places that it was mentioned in you should use the refractor.

1. right click on whatever you're changing its name.
2. **refractor**.
3. **rename/rename file**.
4. it will ask you for the new name and whether you want to change it everywhere (even in comments if you want) or not.
5. choose what you see fit and click **refractor**, he will then check where it exists and ask for confirmation on all the place he found what you're changing name and if you're 100% sure to change its name there.

**warning** : sometimes refractor operations are non reversible so you should double check before clicking **do refractor**.

as for the name up there its called project name and you can change it as instructed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276872/change-project-name-on-android-studio)

Comment: That does not answer the question